# Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer, not-an-answer

Sorry mods, another one of those "a one liner isn't enough of an explanation and I can't fit all of this in *another* flag" posts.

So...

[What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/10751219#10751219)

To the question

> #### Overriding equals and hashCode in Java
>
> What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?

(yes, that is the entire question - not a bad one, and rather straight forward in that a common sense reading of an answer should be able to identify if the answer itself answers the question by identifying issues or pitfalls with overriding equals and hashCode)

The answer

> Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals().

I flagged this as not an answer which was disputed.

I then flagged it with a custom mod message:

> I'd like to appeal the previous disputed NAN flag on this answer. The question is "What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?" - the answer is "You can do it in eclipse with this menu option" which doesn't at all address the any parts of the question (about the pitfalls or issues)." Please delete this answer or turn it into a comment.

Which was:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I'm confused.  This is a non-answer.  Its like having a question on Cooking that is "What issues and pitfalls when cooking with apples" and getting back an answer of "You can use a apple core remover to remove the core".

Yes, one *can* use such a tool in a way that is tangential to the question topic.  However, it doesn't actually answer anything about the issues or pitfalls. Or things to watch out for.  Or even things to watch out for when using the wizard.

The answer *might* answer the question of "what tool can I use to generate hashCode and equals" (or core an apple).  I fail to see any issues or pitfalls that the answer has in it.  ***Maybe*** if one just read the title of the question and not the body of it, the question could be interpreted as "(How do I) Override equals and hashCode in Java" - but that's not the body of the question.

Thus, I believe this is not an answer to the question and should either be converted to a comment or deleted.

If one *really* thinks it is an answer (posted May 25th, 2012), it is a subset of the material in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27604/289086) in the question that was posted August 26th, 2008... and has comments that tell how to do this operation in other IDEs... and the '12 answer adds nothing new to the answers in the question.

<sup><sub>That question could probably use a good cleaning (and it is still getting 'answers')... there's at least one answer that appears to be a comment replying to a deleted answer, and a bunch of other questionable answers that don't really appear to answer the question... but those would be other flags... and I suppose this question is far from alone.</sub></sup>

---

The accepted attempt at an answer has since been deleted by a mod.  For those who don't have 10k rep, the comments are of some value in understanding the issues here.

[image]

I've flagged this question to undelete the answer, but the flag was declined.

Comment: It may be a wrong answer, but it is *still an attempt at answering*. Downvote the damn thing and move on.

Comment: Answers that "miss the point" are still attempts at answering the question, just misguided ones.

Comment: @Martijn (and Bolt), by that logic, "Oh, the huge manatee!" is also *an attempt at answering*. Looks like the consensus is dead and we don't know what to do with those answers anymore.

Comment: I have to side with @MichaelT here, it does not attempt to answer the question at all.

Comment: @BoltClock by that logic, anyone who fails at reading comprehension for a question can post whatever answer they want.

Comment: @Stijn: It attempts to answer *a* question. It may be a gross misread, but that doesn't make it a candidate for NAA.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the flag description clearly says "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer **the** question.", not "**a** question".

Comment: @Stijn: You can still see how it is related to the question here.

Comment: @MichaelT: Exactly.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: No, it isn't. It's extremely obvious that "Oh, the huge manatee!" isn't a valid answer to any conceivably on-topic question here.

Comment: @BoltClock You are suggesting I should change this from a discussion to a feature request "get rid of NAA flag because no one can read simple questions anymore"?

Comment: I agree with the premise of this question. I've flagged a few answers as not an answer and been declined too on very similar grounds. Generally the answerer spots a few keywords in the question and provides a stock answer that completely misses the point of the question. The link between the answer and the question is pretty tenuous in this case.

Comment: I did not suggest that. You did.

Comment: @BoltClock, okay, that example was maybe too ironic. Let's run with something even more silly: Would "Unicorns can codegen these methods for you" be NAA (because of unicorns) or not (because it does refer to the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods)?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Joke answers are an entirely different category, particularly because sometimes a joke answer *can* actually answer a question. For that reason, NAA is not meant for joke answers.

Comment: Another similar example that I ran into myself the other day: an answer appears to relate to the question by context, but it is essentially a "how" answer to a "why" question (and, despite comments from the OP, the answerer seems unable to grasp the difference). Should it be deleted by a moderator?

Comment: @BoltClock that answer is fresh, it has an active set of comments from the person asking it to the answerer explaining why it doesn't answer it.  It has a negative score and can be addressed by 20k users (or fixed). Things that are several years old, with an inactive user, with a positive score that cannot be deleted without a concerted effort, that fail a simple reading of the question, that cannot be flagged otherwise *are* the exceptions that one expects moderators to deal with.  Its not technically wrong or right at issue - its not an answer and should be deleted or turned into a comment.

Comment: @BoltClock, maybe not necessarily by a moderator, but I sure voted for it to be deleted. That answer is little more than noise and the answerer apparently does not understand it is not related to the question, even after the questioner left explicit comments. IMHO there is no benefit in keeping it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why did you undo my edit to the *When to flag...* answer? While I disagree with you and Bolt, it obviously confused a number of us so I thought it'd be useful to have an example there.

Comment: @Stijn: I just wrote you a comment there. I think your edit is premature still.

Comment: While you guys were busy talking about this answer, I took an action - and voted to delete it. ) Still not sure about the difference between this case and a typical VLQ one.

Comment: @raina77ow one can't flag a positive scored question as VLQ. The answer, when I came to it was +4/-0 and the only options where flag for a mod (to delete or convert) with NAA, or custom, or bring it up in meta for meta effect or in chat to get those votes (both of which people are complaining about in other meta questions).  The least disruptive option appeared to be flag for a mod to clean it up. Alas, the meta effect is taking action.

Comment: @MichaelT Oh, my mistake - didn't check the score balance; when I got there, it was already -1. Now I think about the reasons to upvote this answer - can't find any, actually. It's kind of telling the world that one can drink water when they're thirsty when the question is about the difference between different flavors of water. ) It's helpful only in theory.

Comment: Has anyone else noticed the [almost identical answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27604/474189) that is currently enjoying a score of 114? The subtle variation in the language used means it's basking in glory rather than the subject of meta.

Comment: @Duncan yep - (the paragraph "If one really thinks it is an answer...").  Note that one possible handling of the NAA might have been "this should have been an edit to that answer."  IMO, there is a lot of deleting that should be done in that question... and the 114 answer would take a *very* concerted effort to delete with 20k delete votes.  However, if every attempt to write an answer is a valid answer, I fear it will be impossible to remove such... well... crap from the elder days because of how it was 2 or 6 years ago and people had different levels of "yep, this gets an up vote."

Comment: @George, that's not as much a complaint as a regret that there is no consistent system we can apply regarding NAA flags. For instance, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) is change to me (we weren't supposed to flag such questions as NAA before, and we are now, except moderators sometimes reject such flags). I only wish we would make up our collective mind once and for all. Now, if I'm alone on this, then it's not a problem and you can safely ignore me :)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker In Shog's "[Answers & Apples taxonomy](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vAUaw.png)" I regard this answer as an orange. Consider the hypothetical question from 6 years ago "How do you sum a list in Python?" and one of the answers is "In perl its use List::Util; $sum = sum @lilst;" - there's an attempt at answering it, maybe... but it failed at reading comprehension. It is an answer to a different question (not this one). It also got some up votes - sufficient that a down vote won't kick it in the auto VLQ queue. Its not even wrong. How should this be flagged (if at all)?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ... realizing that the other options are to get a meta effect, or a chat vigilante group to go cast down votes on it so it can be deleted.  Those approaches seem to garner a rather "Stack Overflow is mean" result when people decry mob voting. I am under the impression that a simple this isn't even an answer to the question flag (or maybe custom one) would result in the cleanest, least disruptive approach to addressing the issue. I wouldn't mind knowing if I should flag the next non-answer or try to find 108 more down votes.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "I'm convinced you're the only one that complains there isn't consensus", I wouldn't be so sure seeing how this question has a net vote of +21

Comment: A somewhat-relevant answer might not be helpful as an actual answer, but as a hint/tip for other readers.

Comment: You can use [@GeorgeStocker's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228097) from my previous question for free.

Comment: @Bolu I am familiar with that post ([one of my own is there too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230481/)). I am curious about how one should go about removing duplicate content in later answers ("If one really thinks it is an answer (posted May 25th, 2012), it is a subset of the material in another answer in the question that was posted August 26th, 2008)" or questions that don't even fundamentally answer the (see [deleted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)).  If the question is highly uprooted (this was at +40) it is either a flag or meta (and some don't like meta).

Comment: The two answer deletions that [George](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268378/) made here [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BDy9w.png) [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vyG5x.png) must be some form of subtle moderator humor that is lost on me.

Comment: @JoshCaswell these deletions suggest that moderators have some... selective ability to read English ([which seems to turn on and off rather randomly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined/268378#comment76308_268409))

Comment: @MartijnPieters : How is `Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()` an attempt to answer the question `What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?`?. You don't need to be either a JAVA expert (I haven't written JAVA code since college) or a native English speaker (I'm a native Dutch speaker myself) to realize that that answer is as relevant to the question as `I like turtles` or `Hi my name is John`.

Comment: @JohnSlegers see Will's answer below. Down vote it. Cast a delete vote if you have one. It is not a moderator issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : IMO, it clearly falls in category 5 of Robert Harvey's answer  `"Thanks," I like turtles, and similar noise.`, which does make it a moderator issue.

Comment: @JohnSlegers nope. It doesn't.

Comment: @JohnSlegers or put differently, if it *clearly* qualified as a #5 post we'd not be having this conversation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : ... which is something that totally boggles my mind. There is no way I can interpret that answer to make it anything but a clear qualification as a #5 post... and I'm not the only one here, juding by the other comments and answer.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: and there are 5 answers here that say a NAA answer is not applicable. We can argue about edge cases like these until we are blue in the face. I'd decline a NAA flag on that post every single time still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : The answer in no way addresses the question asked. I don't see what makes this an edge case.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: yes, you registered your opinion. I got it. Did you register my disagreement?

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I registered your opinion, yes, but I fail to make any sense of it whatsoever. I couldn't care less about this issue, though, so let's just agree to disagree. Meanwhile, I'll make sure to avoid flagging ANY answer as `Not an answer` for being a #5 case, as there appears to be no unambiguous way to determine whether an answer belongs in that particular category.

Answer (score 62):

What mods are looking for when they see a "Not an Answer" flag:

1. Attempts to communicate with another user.
2. Using the answer space to ask a question.
3. The OP posting an answer to clarify their question or add additional detail.
4. Attempts to bump the question as in "I'm having the same problem."
5. "Thanks," [I like turtles,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CMNry4PE93Y) and similar noise.

All of these things are implied in the flag reason:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an **edit**, a **comment**, another **question**, or **deleted altogether**.

If you're not flagging for one of these things, *do not use the "Not an Answer" flag.*  Instead, cast a custom moderator flag, and write a description explaining why you think the "answer" is harmful to the site, and should be forcibly removed by a moderator.

**Pro Tip:** Mods *do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags.*  If your flag requires a mod to evaluate an answer from the question's perspective, do not use a "Not an Answer" flag on it.

Comment: Aside from the whole flagging debate: the answer is removed now, but I believe it to be valuable information still. Considering its short length, would it be possible to convert it to a comment instead? Equally, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39768/1864167) should undergo the same treatment since it is of the same kind.

Comment: I think that the point op is making is that the particular post he flagged goes in the reason number 4. Which can be tied to the **it does not attempt to answer the question** part of the flag message. I'm not necessarily saying I agree (though I kinda do), but this answer doesn't really helps to convince op otherwise either

Comment: @Lamak: There's no value judgment here.  I'm simply telling you the mechanics by which *all* of the mods on Stack Overflow process the "Not an Answer" flag.

Comment: I see that and I appreciate the clarification of how the posts flagged as NAA are managed. But it still doesn't really say why the particular answer flagged by op can't be seen as "General meanderings that aren't an answer attempt" or how it goes against the "it does not attempt to answer the question" part of the flag reason

Comment: @Lamak: Since that phrase appears to be being interpreted broadly, I've changed it to a phrase that is more specific.  The phrase "it does not attempt to answer the question" is also more narrow than you are interpreting it; moderators *do not look at the technical merit of an answer when moderating.*

Comment: Either way, I think that you "Pro Tip" clarifies this issue, good way of putting it

Comment: In this case, the flag reasons need rewording. What you're describing is what I would either call spam or posting in the wrong place. (Apparently, the spam reason means something else, though.) It seems to me that the flag reasons lack intuitiveness. Maybe that's for historical reasons, where the reasons used to have one meaning but have come to mean something else. Regardless, the flag reason should more directly represent how mods interpret it.

Comment: "Pro Tip: Mods do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags." yet the LQRQ do show the question, so user can evaluate an answer in a specific context. Why moderators don't? Is there any feature request that should be done? I remember that even the 10k tools allowed users to read the question in the same page, why mods don't have such feature?

Comment: @Braiam: Mods do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags, because there is no need to do so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey there is then a massive difference in the workflow of NAA's flags when reviewed by moderators and the rest of us, which probably needs to be addressed by SE.

Comment: @Braiam: Just look at my answer.  That's the logic you should be following.  Requiring mods to look at the question when evaluating NAA flags would dramatically increase the cognitive load, while not significantly improving the correctness of the moderator actions.

Comment: So, you are saying that the community has no way of removing an answer posted in the wrong question (check [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268675/792066))? And if that's the logic, why reviewers aren't asked the same?

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the question were displayed alongside the flagged answer, couldn't mods skip reading it in most cases? E.g., if the answer is "This worked, thanks!", you don't need to pay any attention to the question. But if the answer is a brief snippet that could either be a short answer or should have been a comment, depending on the question, one could skim the question to see if the answer is even semantically valid (without attempting any technical evaluation).

Comment: @Michelle: I prefer that users cast a custom moderator flag for those situations.

Comment: So, how is answering a question like `What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?` with `Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals().` any different from answering it with `I like turtles`?! You don't need to be a JAVA expert to see why both answers are equally irrelevant to the question asked. Even a very basic knowledge of the English language should suffice.

Comment: @JohnSlegers: [As a mod, I don't want to be focused on the finer points of answer definitions. That conversation does not interest me at all. What does interest me is removing posts from the site that clearly do not belong, regardless of the reason they were brought to my attention, and not having to worry about getting into another hopeless argument on Meta over what the definition of "is" is.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318038)

Comment: @RobertHarvey : You explicitly said that the kind of answers mods are looking for when they see a "Not an Answer" flag includes answer of type `"Thanks," I like turtles, and similar noise.` When people can't seem to agree whether a question belongs to this category, IMO that's an issue that needs to be resolved, as it can result in people being banned from flagging **while correctly applying the rules of this community** as they interpret it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey : Having said that, I see you did address this issue @ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318038/its-time-to-quietly-retire-the-not-an-answer-flag?lq=1, and it's an approach that does make sense after reading the many answers and comments here. Not sure why your question is getting downvoted...

Answer (score 33):

This is what happens when you ask moderators to delete answers based on their technical validity:

[image: An animated GIF of two men dressed as janitors, whacking furiously and meaninglessly at a tangerine-colored iMac.]

Mods are janitors.  They are not supposed to judge the technical validity of an answer.  They are supposed to clean up the trash and mop the sick off the floors.

So don't expect much more than lots of grunting and bashing of ugly Apple hardware if you flag an answer because it is technically invalid.  Mods tend to leave issues like that for the community to handle with downvotes and delete votes.

Comment: per my reading, it's not about technical validity but about plain English. "What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding _blah_?" -- "Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate _blah_". Answer is [not even wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

Comment: @gnat Why is it wrong?  You'll have to explain the technical reasons for me to understand.  *bashes imac*

Comment: what _technical_ reasons does one need to understand word "blah"? it's plain English. And I repeat, answer is not wrong. Neither it is correct. It's **[not even wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong)**

Comment: @gnat You'll have to explain the technical reasons why the original answer was not correct for the original question.  It isn't hard.  Think about it.

Comment: sure no problem,  "Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate blah" does not even attempt to answer the question "What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding blah?"

Comment: @gnat why can't you override by using Eclipse -> Source -> Generate?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker probably because it really isn't an answer. As how we understand and use the phrase IRL.  However the flag is targeted at answers that really aren't answers as we categorize them on SO--another question, spam, "MEE TOOO", etc.  Something that doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I don't see what there is to think about. I know nothing about Java other than being able to get a general idea of what certain code does, yet I know that it doesn't answer the question. The question could be "What are the pitfalls of doing *foo* in Brainfuck" and I'd still know that "if you use Brainfuck Studio 2000, you can generate *foo* via this menu" does not answer the question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I do understand why moderators tend to be careful when deleting content, but like gnat said, this has nothing to do with having a technical grounding in a certain subject, instead it has everything to do with being able to read English. That's the point I was trying to make. All I know about Brainfuck is that it uses some characters like `<` and `>`, yet I'd feel confident when deleting such a hypothetical answer.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker "If someone has to think about how the answer 'doesn't apply' to the question, then you probably shouldn't flag it as 'not an answer'. I'm not sure why that's so hard to grok." Your comment defies its own logic. It suggests I have to think about the meaning of "Not an Answer" while simultaneously suggesting that mods shouldn't have to think about why it's not an answer. It is literally not an answer. Why is that any harder to grok than the fact that "Not an Answer" apparently doesn't mean "not an answer"? (Don't read this too hard or long. You'll get a headache. ;) )

Comment: @gnat that answer could indeed be considered an answer to the question. With that knowledge the pragmatic programmer doesnt need to know about the pitfalls, instead they can make use of their tools and move on. It may not be the best answer or the answer the OP was expecting, but it is an answer. Perhaps if he had worded it slightly different you may have considered it an answer, e.g. 'You dont need to worry about that, you can use Eclipse to generate them...' Shame it was deleted already

Comment: The general meaning of "not an answer" really is "a comment, a question, a discussion, a complaint, a rant, a ninja, a house, a spaceship etc.. anything that's not an answer at all". A wrong answer is still an answer.

Answer (score 18):

For me, who is not a Java dev, that looks like a valid, if low quality, answer. Why would a mod think differently?

At your privilege level, you can downvote. You can also go to chat which has Java experts with more than 20k reputation and have them look at it and maybe delete it.

But a moderator cannot and should not deal with answers which are incorrect, even if they don't seem to relate to the question at all.

In your shoes I'd downvote, maybe flag as VLQ and move on.

Comment: I agree with this.  The simple fact is we cannot expect moderators to be technically qualified enough the technical accuracy of an answer in all technologies, so if an answer **looks** like a valid attempt at an answer, then NAA shouldn't be applicable.

Comment: It's not even VLQ... if anything the VLQ flag is even less applicable than NAA. But you know, whatever.

Comment: @BoltClock, I do agree VLQ is less appropriate here. If NAA and VLQ are both inapplicable, should the answer not be flagged at all?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - That's right, the answer should **not** be flagged at all. It should be down-voted (with optional comment) and then perhaps deleted by the community, but not by moderators.

Comment: @ChrisF unfortunately that involves invoking the meta effect or chat room group down voting to get the question low enough score to get 20k rep users to down vote it... Which *other* meta questions are decrying. What is the least disruptive option to handle (almost)non-answers?

Comment: @ChrisF, I understand. I believe the issue here is that we are not used to cases where we shouldn't delegate the resolution to the moderator team. Maybe a FAQ like "In which situations should I *not* flag?" would help.

Comment: @MichaelT - perhaps we should be training people to do searches for negatively voted questions to see if they can be deleted.

Comment: @ChrisF what about the ones that aren't negative yet?  When I first flagged the answer (before voting on it), it was +4/-0. That isn't enough to kick it to the auto VLQ flag queue, or have a 20k delete vote it... But it was still (almost)not an answer.

Comment: I made a trivial edit so I could downvote.  Specifically, `Very Low Quality` has a specific meaning. It means, "This post is garbage, has no redeeming value, and is actively stinking up the place. Delete it."  That's an even higher bar than "Not an answer".

Answer (score 14):

The bar is pretty high for 'Not an answer'.

It should be *immediately obvious* to someone with no experience in the tag that the post does not attempt to address the question.

If it's not *immediately obvious*, your choices are:

- Custom flag explaining why the post is 'not an answer'
- Downvote
- Move on

If the post *even appears* to attempt to address the question posed, *your not an answer flag will be declined*.

Comment: I am curious about what part of "Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()." addresses the question "What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?".  I can identify no *suggestion* of an issue or pitfall in the answer. Instead it says "here is a tool that will do it sometimes".  We are dealing with an entirety of two sentences here - one sentence for the question, one sentence for the answer.  It should be possible to point to at least one of the 10 words in the answer and say "this is an issue or pitfall".

Comment: haven't used Eclipse in ages, but how do you know that there is no help pop-up when you generate hashCode and equals?  maybe it shows a help file explaining why's and how's?

Comment: @MichaelT: "Not an answer" != "Not an answer to this question" #lern2readplz&thku

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So if someone were to answer that question with an explanation of how to sort a list in Python, that wouldn't count as "not an answer"? The message doesn't just say "not an answer" - it says "it does not attempt to answer *the* question".

Comment: @Michelle: No, it would not. It would, however, be downvoted to oblivion and deleted almost immediately. No need to get moderators involved and waste their time. And who are you to decide that the author "did not attempt to answer _the_ question"? Maybe they made an attempt but have a mental illness of some kind. Are you now _discriminating_??

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit But this answer wasn't going to be downvoted and deleted naturally. The flag message also says "it should possibly be a comment", implying that semi-related things that aren't actually an answer to the actual question fall under the NAA flag.

Comment: @Michelle: The problem is, I didn't say anything absurd. Sorry that you're continually missing the point, but don't take it out on me with rudeness and hostility, thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was originally trying to actually discuss the flag description, but you don't seem to be interested. Sorry for any hostility.

Comment: @Michelle If this answer wasn't going to be downvoted and gotten rid of by the community; that's a warning sign that maybe it needs a custom flag.  Why should I, as someone who has only touched Java twice in his life, be able to overrule the 4 people who upvoted that question that thought it had value? The Not an answer flag is for clear posts that do not attempt to address the question.  This attempts to address the question (poorly). It is an answer, just a poor one. That having been said, the best approach *when there could be doubt* is either 1) downvote, or 2) a custom flag. Is that hard?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It is in fact "Not an answer to this question" #lern2readplz&thku. (as was already posted, the flag description says "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question.")

Comment: @Lamak: I've already explained why that description does not fit.

Comment: Why are you suggesting a custom flag? Custom flags can't be reviewed by non-mods and I've seen plenty of flags rejected for that reason.

Comment: @bjb568 Right now, 'Not an answer' flags also go to moderators. So... Yea. I'd rather have a custom flag explaining what's actually wrong (and what you want me to do about it) than a canned flag where I don't see the issue.  If you're worried about a flag getting declined; you're in the wrong business. *I* have declined flags (even after I became a moderator). It's going to happen. Don't worry about that.

Comment: I'm not worried about flags being declined, I'm worried that I'm doing something wrong if I'm getting flags declined. "Please delete because X" "declined - the community can handle it itself"

Comment: Why doesn't this "answer" clear the bar you give in your answer?  Looks like it does to me.

Comment: @tmyklebu Because http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/16587

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: OK, that makes *much* more sense.  (The answer OP reproduced still seems to clear your bar, but Robert's explanation in terms of the site's mechanics pretty much covers how "not an answer" should be used.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Maybe I attempted to answer the question when I typed "The flargle spimmed jugglers anti-bottles of grog jam my bum". Maybe I have [aphasia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphasia).

Comment: @neminem: Yeah, maybe.

Comment: @neminem Ironically, your "answer" was the only one that hasn't been downvoted.

Comment: @user000001 You mean the one that was sadly deleted only seconds after I posted it (not that I expected any less, but still). Kinda hard to downvote posts that are immediately deleted.

Comment: @MichaelT If you look at the question's title; the answers appear to be answers -- part of this is due to a really inaccurate question title.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker yep.  I made note of that with the sentence starting "Maybe if one just read the title of the question and not the body of it"  The title was 6 words long at the time, but that shouldn't excuse someone from reading the 11 words of the body of the question... or noting that the top (accepted) answer is addressing something else, or that one of the other answers said *exactly* the same thing.  There are multiple failures of reading and reading comprehension with that answer.  None of which should have excused its forum-like behavior and not answering the question.

Comment: @MichaelT That's a pretty narrow view, read my latest post for more on why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268437/titles-matter-in-questions-edit-those-first

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I do agree about the title being very important.  I lament the removal of the 10k anon feedback explorer as that can be a hint about what people are expecting more than the up and downvotes - is it what people from google are expecting to find and is this answer what they were looking for?  With that, my attempts (on P.SE) of fixing broken titles has less guidance now than it did before. It's harder to see what answers are genuinely helpful and not up vote for effort. But I still don't see skipping the body of the question and answering the title as an answer.

Comment: In the strictest sense; the answer is whatever helps people.  For the title given, people from Google were looking for a specific answer -- an answer that received over 100 upvotes. That's a non-trivial number for 'not being an answer', and we make Stack Overflow a worse place by nuking that content because the OP couldn't be bothered to write an accurate title, and no one who complained about those answers could be bothered to edit the title to reflect the question.

Comment: I'm not a JAVA expert either, but I DO find it *immediately obvious* that  `Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals()` is not an answer to the question `What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?`. I DO find it *immediately obvious* that that answer is as relevant as `I like turtles`.

Comment: @JohnSlegers What are you referring to? And why are you commenting on this over a year and a half later?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker : I was just randomly browsing the meta questions. Is commenting on old meta questions frowned upon? Anyway, I was refering to the specific case mentioned in the question, that in my opinion is a clear-cut case for the `Not an answer` flag because it completely fails to address the question in any way whatsoever, no less than `I like turtles` would.

Answer (score 13):

Consider an answer to *this* question (on meta) that looks like, say:

> Here is a simple way to sort a list of ints in c#:
>
> ```
> var values = new int[5,7,3];
> values = values.OrderByDescending(p => p).ToList();
> ```
>
> Hopefully that answers your question.

It's an answer to *a* question, yes? I claim that keeping this answer makes just about as much sense as keeping that one, but I'm not a mod. It makes some sense that the *NAA* flag would be declined, as it does look like an answer at first glance. I do not agree, though I have already seen on meta that this topic is a divisive one, that answers to clearly a question only at most very tangentially related to the question that was asked, should only be downvoted rather than removed.

I've flagged a small handful of questions like that with custom flags - some have been accepted, some haven't, indicating that higher-rep/mod users also aren't completely clear on where to draw that line.

Answer (score -3):

> Question: Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?
>
> To the question:

```
Overriding equals and hashCode in Java
What issues / pitfalls must be considered when overriding equals and hashCode?
```

> The answer:

```
Sometimes, you can use Eclipse -> Source -> Generate hashCode() and equals().
```

> I flagged this as not an answer which was disputed.
>
> I'm confused. This is a non-answer.

You are allowed to not understand questions and answers, you can use a comment to ask for clarification or use search tools to educate yourself about the subject. Using comments to cast [disparaging](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disparage#Verb) remarks and flags to protest or further your position isn't helpful.

You are allowed to ask a useful question in a comment, vote (either way or not at all) without so much as a comment, or move on to something else.

If you read EclipseSource.com's article "[The 3 things you should know about hashCode()](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/)" you will see this text at the end of the article:

"To be on the safe side, let the Eclipse IDE generate the equals and hashCode functions as a pair: Source > Generate hashCode() and equals()….".

Thus, **it is** a recommended answer.

A ***better*** answer might have been derived from "[Java – How to override equals and hashCode](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/)" or "[Why <s>to</s> Override equals(Object) and hashCode() method?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/override-equalsobject-hashcode-method/)"

If you don't like the answer then you can move on, UpVote, DownVote, or leave a constructive criticism in the comments about how it could be improved.

You will **earn more reputation** by making a helpful edit or posting your own better answer - thus that might be your preferred course of action.

---

There also seems to be the same complaint about this answer (which you included in image format, since it was deleted):

> I think it's right to [burniate](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=burniated), the tag very [ambiguous](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambiguous). Should I start now?

This answer **claims** that "... overriding equals and hashCode" is the right thing to do, apparently the issues and pitfalls don't merit discussion. The words "should I start now" are a rally [call to action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_to_action_(marketing)).

Part fact, part opinion, and terse; which is a programming style.

Apparently the OP felt sufficiently in favor of this answer that they choose it.

People are permitted to UpVote incorrect answers, DownVote correct answers, not vote at all; the OP is free to choose any answer, no answer, or write their own answer.

What is also permitted is to not understand, it's OK, go ahead.

What is not wanted is for people to troll or for Mod's to be busied with flags they will reject.

It is perfectly acceptable to write here in Meta your question asking about this, don't misunderstand my answer. Those *answers* are "answers", and they possess the minimum amount of quality to bypass the VLQ flag too.

Those answers are not as bad as the '*[Bulldog Clip answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/432372/246019)*' ([What do you call this clamp in English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432371/what-do-you-call-this-clamp-in-english/432541)) which ***used to*** have well over 100 UpVotes and remains the 'chosen answer' - despite the **undeniable fact** that it is incorrect.

I don't deny that those answers could have been longer and dwelled on each point at length, fact is that they did not; but that doesn't reduce them to being 'not an answer' or 'no answer at all' - there is an answer that either you don't like or wasn't well explained specifically **to you**.

It is odd/annoying/unhelpful the way things work here sometimes. You can ask for change.

Asking in a comment to the answer in question for clarification or a source link would (might?) have satisfied you **if** the answerer chooses to respond to your inquiry. The flag was (is) correctly declined.

Comment: Ha ha. I'm British and I would definitely call it a bulldog clip.

Comment: @JeremyP - Yes, lots of controversy. The reason that it's not a "Bulldog Clip" is because the patented name specifically refers to a different style of clip. The reason it is a "[Binder Clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binder_clip) is stated on it's Wikipedia webpage: "A binder clip, less commonly known as a banker's clip or foldover clip, ... The term "foldback clip" is used in the United Kingdom to describe this invention (not to be confused with a Bulldog clip, an older device with the same function, which is stronger and **has rigid rather than folding** handles).".

Comment: No you are wrong. Well, technically you are right, but we tend to call all clips that look like that "bulldog clip" much like we call all vacuum cleaners "hoover".

Comment: @JeremyP - Would you call [cyclonic separation technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_(company)#Cyclonic_separation_technology) a hoover? - Different, but does the same thing; or does it ...

Comment: No that's a Dyson.

Comment: LOL.   - Let's call it a [Tornado](https://tornadovac.com/common/index.aspx).

Comment: Sounds good to me, but be aware, if you said to a Brit "a Dyson is a kind of hoover" they would understand you. Some of the more pedantic ones would point out that Hoover is a brand name just like Heroin.

Answer (score -15):

"Not an answer" is *not* the same as "not *the* answer", or "it looks like this answer comes from misunderstanding the question".

It means... "not an answer". Like asking a follow-up question, or spamming, or copy-pasting song lyrics.

It's self-evident that this must be the meaning of the flag, unless you think a small number of moderators having the power to decide on the correctness/validity of individual answers, in contrast to the democratic nature of the voting system, is *really* what Stack Overflow is and/or should be about.

Your flag was invalid; instead you should downvote the post.

Comment: What the heck's with these downvotes on mine and George's answers?!

Comment: Not sure, but it might have to do with them believing your answer doesn't address the question as the custom flag was the one that was declined (the NAA flag was only disputed). Having said that, "not an answer" is indeed not the correct flag to use.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: The custom message is an appeal about the NAA having been disputed. The NAA was correct to be disputed, so the appeal was baseless and was right to be rejected. It's all the same thing. Certainly, asking moderators to delete answers because one person says they're wrong is fraking despotic.

Comment: Song lyrics are an excellent answer to the question, "What's a good passphrase to recommend?" :)

Comment: Second's [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268372/2982225) has 4 downvotes. Robert's one is the only answer that got spared.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: Not really. It has two.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Some people, myself included, believe that answers that are clearly answers to *some* question, but equally clearly not answers to the question they were posted as an answer to, aren't really answers. For instance, I posted an answer to an obviously unrelated question to *this* question, and it got immediately deleted, as it should. (I do agree that in such cases, it makes sense not to flag as NAA, to make it clear why you're flagging, but I do *not* agree that that means that it *is* an answer. Yes, I am aware this means more work for mods, but that's not my fault.)

Comment: @neminem: It's additional work that the mods will not take on.

Comment: @neminem: Yes, I know some people think that. You people are wrong.

Comment: So if I go spamming up questions with "THIS IS MY PONY", it should rightly get deleted, but if I go spamming up questions (that don't have anything to do with javascript) with "Use jquery!", everyone should just downvote and move on? I'm not trolling, I'm honestly confused how that makes sense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: You're getting downvotes because your answer tries and fails to address the question.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Fails how? Or was that just a funny? (Can't tell)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The answer referenced clearly does not "attempt to answer the question," which is the description of the "not an answer" flag.  (Robert Harvey's answer does an excellent job of describing why OP's flagging behaviour isn't productive, however.)

Comment: @tmyklebu: I don't know why you're repeating all the stuff I've already debunked. Sigh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Because you didn't debunk anything.  It's real easy to repeat nothing.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Not my fault if you don't comprehend basic logic and/or English *shrug* Good night

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's *you* who's failing at reading comprehension, as has been pointed out many times already.  You're welcome to point out the logic error you're alleging.