# Should I do anything to make an existing question easier to find?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The situation is as follows. I have a problem in an application that I am writing. I google the problem and I find nothing. I do a search on Stack Overflow and I don't find anything either. So I start writing my own question.

But right before I post it I notice among the suggested existing questions one that might be about the same thing as I wanted to ask, just worded completely differently (or with a broad title that doesn't exactly suggest what the contents might be).

So I end up not posting the question to avoid making a duplicate, but I already spent some time writing the question and if did that then others might have done that too (and some might end up doing in the future).

Should I do anything in such case? I presume posting my duplicate question anyway is a bad idea?

Comment: I would edit the original question instead of posting a duplicate.

Comment: `There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words`. [How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Comment: @mehow but then some people who would find the question with the original title might not find it anymore. Perhaps we need a way to suggest alternative titles for a question, to feed search results?

Comment: @Stijn yeah I think I like the idea but as of today I would rather check the views on the question. If they are low and the question is "hard" to find through google then I would definitely edit the title and body so it becomes an easier find

Comment: Follow-up on my previous comment: looks like this was suggested back in 2009 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21285/alternative-question-titles-to-reduce-duplicates).

Comment: [If the question has a title that isn't descriptive of the problem, then fix that question's title.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268437/titles-matter-in-questions-edit-those-first)

Answer (score 2):

Fix the title of the question you found, so that it has more relevance for Google searchers.

You can suggest an edit.  Make sure that you explain in the edit description that you are improving the title so that Google searchers can find the post easier.