# The System should tell me why my title has been rejected

Tags: feature-request, title

On an average it might take me 2-3 minutes to type a question and clearly describe everything about the question.  In some cases it will take me 10-12 minutes to come up with a suitable title for the question, after getting rejected many times.

**Shouldn't it at least tell me what the error is (precisely)**?  It should come up with a more convincing explanation than:

> This title does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it clearly summarizes your problem and uses proper grammar. You can put details in the body of your question.

After this it's just trial and error until the title of the question gets accepted.

It would be a useful addition to the system if it could tell us what is wrong with the title, instead of just stating it doesn't meet standards.

Comment: point taken. edited. still , i request for that feature, to give more details about the error in title .should i explicitly mention that in the question ?

Comment: It looks much better now. And now that it's easier to read, I can see that's what you meant. You might want to make your request for the feature a tad clearer- I would help you, but on Meta you can't edit another user's post with out 2k rep.

Comment: What was the title that you had a n issue with?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker ..this prticular time, i was asking a question about "pointers vs references " in c++ . i tried almost all possible question framings that i could come up with, it still didn't get accepted. e.g "why references exist in c++? "/ "what is the need for references" / "pointers vs refernces" etc.

Comment: @guitar_geek That seems like a red flag that perhaps the question isn't a question that would do well on our site.

Comment: EXACTLY . that is what the error message should have been "question wouldn't do well on site.avoid posting such question "  . so that i wouldn't waste time trying to come up with a title and drop the idea of posting this question. instead it keeps telling me to come up with better title

Comment: Well, it might not be able to tell that just by the title; just that it is a bad title and doesn't fit the check it uses. Perhaps after a set number of title fails, then it could say that.

Comment: By the way, to make your feature-request a bit more... Obvious, perhaps add something like this to your question: "It would be a useful addition to the system for it to tell you what is wrong with your title, instead of just stating it doesn't meet standards."

Comment: done. hope you don't sue for plagiarism . jk. :D

Comment: Not at all, if you can't think of a better way to word it, I think mine is plenty clear. I do think it would be a helpful idea, myself, so glad to assist.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I would edit it to help the OP garner proper attention to the question... But I have yet to reach that rep on SO. :) So all I may do is suggest.

Comment: Now that the question is far clearer, title included, @GeorgeStocker has about the best answer you'll probably get to your feature request, guitar_geek.

Comment: why is my question at -2 points ? seriously ? Is this such a bad question ?

Comment: @guitar_geek downvotes on feature-requests on Meta are usually to show that people do not agree with your feature. You don't lose rep for it.

Comment: good to know :) thanks @Kendra ..also does this mean, i won't get +rep even if my question were at +40 ?

Comment: That's exactly what it means. There's no rep on per-site metas.

Answer (score 11):

The problem with the system telling you why your title is bad is that it encourages people to try to game a title that meets the minimum standards without actually fixing their title to be useful to others.

You even mention that you just tried different variations of the same terse title without taking a step back and actually trying to use your title to convey what someone would search for if they had your issue.

Your title [is one of the most important parts of your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268437/titles-matter-in-questions-edit-those-first) (if not *the* most important part).

It's what is going to draw people in, get eyeballs on your question, get answers to your question, and serve as Google juice for people who have your issue in the future.

Write it well, and receive upvotes; write it poorly, and well... get rejected by the system.

A title that is rejected by our automated system is a canary in a coal mine: It's there to warn you that either your title actually needs work; or maybe your question isn't one that would do well on our site.

Your title should include the following not to be rejected by the system:

- Capitalized words where appropriate
- No misspelled words
- No shorthand speak ('u' instead of 'you', 'y' insetad of 'why')
- No excessive punctuation
- Not use the word 'problem', 'help', 'hard', 'thanks', 'please', 'vs', 'confuse', 'understand', 'best' or any of those variants

More than that, it should include the following

- More than 4 words
- Succinctly yet completely detail the problem *you would search for* if you had this issue.

The first set of bullet points are table stakes -- the absolute minimum a title should have; the second set will help you get upvotes for your question (and create value for the site and other users).

Comment: Or ["urgent"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aurgent) or ["plz"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aplz) .. or ["tia"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Atia) (only one, but let's not *encourage les autres*). ["Thanks"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Athanks), on the other hand, *is* allowed.

Comment: I do wonder, George: Would my suggestion in the comments above still be a viable idea? After so many title rejects, suggesting reviewing the question as it may not be a fit for SO? Or is that still a possible way to cause gaming of the system?

Comment: @Kendra I like your suggestion: After 5 or 6 times trying, it could be helpful to say, "Take a step back. What would a user search for if they had your problem? Try that as your title."  The SE team knows how many times a title is rejected; so they'd have that data -- they'd need to do some testing to see if including that helps or hurts matters.

Comment: I think it might help, at least with the users who do care enough to make it relevant. Though I haven't hit the issue myself (all my titles have gone through first try), I know if I had ever hit that kind of message, I would've taken a step back and looked at it again.

Comment: "The problem with the system telling you why your title is bad is that it encourages people to try to game a title that meets the minimum standards without actually fixing their title to be useful to others." I think exactly the opposite is true -- to the extent that I mis-read this sentence the first couple times.  I believe that *not* telling the user why their title was rejected encourages mindless fuzzing, and lowers the quality of the title from what they had originally proposed to some bastardized, stochastic word soup.