# Amending subject line to attract searches

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, title

I have just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25473122) and, because the process of discovering the answer was so revelatory to me, I amended the question so that its subject line reflected my solution, rather than the problem the OP, without hindsight, originally faced.

To save you chasing the link, the original subject was

```
Perl script not preserving unicode strings - why?
```

and after I discovered the problem, I changed it to

```
Perl UTF-8 encoding on DATA and ARGV file handles
```

My question is whether this is a legitimate edit on my part.

I am far more interested in the challenges that the questions hold than the reputation points that my answer may gain, but Stack Overflow's core purpose is to create a library of solutions to programming problems, so better indexing of the content can only further that.

I can imagine many problems if similar editing becomes commonplace, not least that those who post an answer will be competing to edit the subject line of the question so as to favour their own answer. But of course that is possible at present and doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: I think it is entirely legitimate.  Very often the "real" issue is a bit different from what the OP originally diagnosed or characterized it as, so it should be changed.

Comment: One small problem with your change is that it's not a question.

Comment: I don't think that sort of edit helps. The question as you phrased it is more likely to be the same thing someone else is trying to figure out. Your edit contains too much of the solution. If a person has the solution, they aren't searching for it.

Comment: @BartoszKP: A huge majority of titles aren't question. It's the subject - the body of the post forms the question

Comment: @Borodin A huge majority of questions are crap, so a counting argument is not the way to go here for sure ;) Every issue can be reworded into a concise summing-up question. And should be, IMHO, of course (that's why I've said it's a "small problem" :) ).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These edits are great! *Thank you!*

Now for the back story on this: there's been [various](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268437) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103053/how-aggressively-should-we-maintain-and-improve-very-popular-questions/103069#103069) about editing the titles of a question. We've been discovering that popular questions have crappy titles. Sooo... why is this a problem? Well, when people are coming from Google, they see the title first, and they click on it. Well, if that title is misleading, then it's not useful for them. And maybe they *can't* even find the right answer, because the title isn't useful.

That isn't very good, is it? As you say, we're supposed to be building a knowledge base of programming questions. And if people can't find the answer to their question easily... something is wrong.

As George said in the first of the questions I linked

> Titles should reflect the actual problem a poster has; not a truncated
>   form meant for Google juice. *If a question title isn't helpful to the
>   average searcher, it's not helpful for us.*
>
> *Titles are the single most important part of the question for a search
>   engine and for the human eye. If the title doesn't accurately reflect
>   the problem, then it should be edited to do so.*

If you feel like doing these edits, that's great: you just made it easier for people to find the answer to their question! Of course there's no obligation to do this, but if you do it makes it easier for future readers to find the answer to their question.

Answer (score 6):

You want to be careful in your title edit that you don't make it harder to find. If I was faced with the same question I not be typing `UTF-8 encoding on DATA and ARGV file handles`.

I think many questions have a two step process. 
Discovery: I have a problem but it is not clear yet. (error message, something not working etc.) So I search for ideas that relate to my original problem. In this stage the original title may be better.

Resolution: I now know what is causing my problem (UTF-8 encoding etc.), but I need to find a specific solution that will fix it. In this case the new title may be more relevant.

Be careful when editing titles because not everyone will know what the problem is yet. I do agree that many titles are not good enough. I appreciate good titles.

Comment: I agree. If you don't know what UTF-8 is, you're going to use the search term "weird characters" or the like, which is what an organic question's title will be. If we edit new vocabulary into the question, then it is hard to find for people that lack the knowledge. If the question-asker knew what UTF-8 is, they would likely recognize the problem on sight and not had the question to begin with.