# Flag on troll answer declined: are these answers really acceptable?

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

A question was posted which had asked for some simple code that chooses a random name from an array in Objective-C.

An answer was subsequently posted which contained the following:

```
NSString * getRandomString(NSArray * names) {
     return "RandomName"; // Joke
}
```

I then flagged the post with a custom flag, noting that it was a troll answer which was not really intended to answer the question. This flag was later declined, saying that "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer".

Are these answers really posts that should be kept and accepted?

Comment: I can't think [where I've seen that before](http://xkcd.com/221/)...

Comment: I'm not sure I'd have flagged that post; it did not need moderator intervention. You commented on it, and it was rightly downvoted. The question was terrible too, got downvotes and is now deleted. We could have done the same with a few 10k+ deletion votes for the answer.

Comment: There's a non-custom "Not an answer" flag which is suitable for "answers" which don't attempt to answer the question.

Comment: If it doesn't NEED moderator attention I don't think it should be flagged. The mods have enough to do.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Flagging `NAA` for technical reasons probably [won't be accepted by mods either](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined/268438#268438) i'm afraid

Comment: @Qantas - why did you *not* flag it as *Not an Answer*? That gets it in the hands of the community, and it avoids the mods.

Comment: While it wasn't really intended to be an answer, NAA is a poor choice of flag as noted above: it's not clearly a non-answer.  If that is truly objectionable (and I don't think that one is), custom flag is the way to go.

Answer (score 62):

Actually, the full answer was this:

> ```
> NSString * getRandomString(NSArray * names) {
>      return "RandomName"; // Joke
> }
> ```
>
> Now instead of `return "RandonName"`, generate a random number between
>   1 and `[names count]` and return that value.

That last sentence makes a lot of difference, because while the code snippet was a bit of a joke, I think they were trying to instruct the asker at the end without spoon-feeding them. Of course, that last sentence isn't really correct, but that makes it seem to me to not be an attempt at trolling.

They also left this comment:

> Care to explain the downvote, the OP needed direction and i think this is a good hint.

which makes me believe that while this was not a good answer, it was not intended as a troll post.

Comment: is there a chance that flagger caught a "draft" of the answer (prior revision, or in grace period) and _Now instead of return..._ part was added after they flagged?

Comment: @gnat - There were no non-grace-period edits, and any flags on the answer came at least an hour after it was left. That should have been the visible state of the answer for both flagger and the moderator who reviewed it.

Answer (score -16):

While technically that answer (probably) answer the question, it's not intended to answer any real problem and is simply a noise.

The intention of the AP (answering person) is quite clear, it's showing to the OP that the question is not precise, because it doesn't formulate clearly what is understood under 'random name'.

However, that is exactly what we have 'unclear what you're asking' close reason for. If someone posts 'answers' which are nothing more like the (a bit) offensive way for saying that the question is poorly worded, it's a noise which should be removed, at least via 'low quality' flags and 'very low quality' queue, to not bother the mods with the handling of that flag.

Comment: -1 for being a pedant. Nobody who asks a simple question should have to dot their i's and cross their t's to that point.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're saying here. It *sounds* like you're saying that the answer is noise and doesn't answer the question. But then you go on to say that you shouldn't bother raising a flag on the answer. So, which is it? Yes, the question should probably be closed. And yes, instead of posting nonsense/joke answers to unclear questions, that person should have voted to close it as unclear. But they didn't, and regardless of whether a question gets closed, ***bad answers still need to be cleaned up***. The debate here is whether this was an answer or not.