# Should a "related reading" answer be flagged?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer

I received an answer recently that I felt conflicted about. It looks like this:

> A very good answer [*inline link*] to a related question
>
> > ***[Title of related question]***
> >
> > *[Excerpt from related answer]*
>
> Please have a look at original question for reference.

The related question is indeed *related* in the sense that it concerns a *related concept* but they're not duplicates. At best, it's *related reading* -- something best left as a comment or postscript to a real answer.

That being said, it's not clear to me whether the user was genuinely attempting to answer the question, so I don't know how to apply [Martijn's guidelines for using the NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2359271) and I'm loath to flag for moderator attention unless absolutely certain it's warranted.

Let me be clear that it *does not answer* the question and *should have been a comment or edit*. However, its content is taken from a high-quality answer to another question. Does a quote of an answer itself necessarily constitute an answer?

The author had already submitted a "real" answer about 10 minutes before, so the approach I took at the time was just to leave a comment suggesting that the author merge the second answer into the first as an edit. Since that approach wasn't effective, should I flag the answer and if so, what flag should I use?

Here are the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24663469/2359271) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324736/2359271).

Comment: That's not an answer.  Should be a comment or a vote to close.  I'd usually flag as NAA and move on.  If I was concerned, I'd leave a custom flag and add my first sentence above.

Comment: If I even have some related reading to post in my answer, I would [make it clear that it's _"Read more:"_ context, not the actual content.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7cfBT.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found some good evidence while writing up the question that if any flag is warranted, "not an answer" is not it.

[Robert's rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/2359271) (heh) from a recent NAA discussion underscore the fact that the broader context of an answer is largely absent when the flag is reviewed:

> **Pro Tip**: Mods *do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags*. If your flag requires a mod to evaluate an answer from
>   the question's perspective, do not use a "Not an Answer" flag on it.

[George goes even further](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268378/2359271) in the same discussion:

> It should be *immediately obvious* to someone with no experience in
>   the tag that the post does not attempt to address the question.
>
> If it's not *immediately obvious*, your choices are:
>
> - Custom flag explaining why the post is 'not an answer'
> - Downvote
> - Move on

So even if this answer "attempts to communicate with another user" and "should possibly be an edit [or] a comment," sending it to the VLQ queue will not be effective.

I think it's obvious that the ideal solution is to engage the user politely and convince them to voluntarily convert their answer to an edit or comment. Failing that, I'm not sure. So this partial self-answer boils down to "whatever you do, don't flag it NAA!"

---

As far as the specific answer that prompted this question, I first decided to comment only:

> This doesn't really seem like an answer to me. Maybe it would be
>   better as a comment or edited into your other answer.

I recently revisited the question and saw that the user hadn't responded to the comment, several weeks later. Since it hadn't been upvoted in that time, I decided to just downvote and move on. **If it were displacing good answers, I would consider raising a custom flag**, but I don't see any real harm in its sitting around with a negative score.

Comment: If you found the answer to your question while write it up, i wonder why you posted it 0__0

Comment: @TJ, because it's okay to do so? I like this answer; it provides insight to reviewing. I will be better because of it.

Comment: @TJ In addition to the above: Maybe there's a better answer. Maybe there are important additions. Maybe I've made an error in judgment, and voting will prove me wrong.

Comment: Even if this were a perfect, comprehensive answer (it is neither), it took me some time (20 minutes?) to piece it together from the context of related discussions. Now someone searching MSO for "related reading" won't have to duplicate that effort.

Comment: I wish people didn't question self-answers all the time. It's really irritating. And while we're on the topic of related links, it kinda makes me feel like we need to tack on "Related reading: <It's OK to ask and answer your own questions>" to every self-answered question that we post just so people recognize that it's perfectly acceptable and perfectly normal behavior. (But then if we have to keep explicitly telling people about this, is it really "normal" behavior anymore?)

Comment: Or to put it another way: I wish *we* didn't have to be held accountable for doing something that's perfectly normal, just because it's not something that is done often.