# Can the text in the mod's canned response for declined NAA flags be changed?

Tags: feature-request, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Heavily inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377440/can-we-have-the-naa-flag-description-changed), suggesting a change to the text of the NAA flag to include the typical canned response for mis-used NAA flags ("The (NAA|Not an Answer) flag should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"), I have a slightly different suggestion.

For [my own experience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377425/why-isnt-this-post-that-doesnt-answer-the-question-but-does-provide-interest) my confusion stemmed entirely from the text of that canned response. I'm more than happy to learn and to update my understanding of how the community works, and declined flags are part of that, but my thought process, upon seeing a fairly highly upvoted answer that was *correct* but *irrelevant to the question* went something like:

- This doesn't answer the question - it's clearly a response to some of the other answers here. It should either be a self-answer to a different question, or a comment on those other answers.
- Raise a NAA flag.
- "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"
- Ah, the moderator has misunderstood my intent with that flag; I didn't mean it was inaccurate or wrong, I just meant that it doesn't answer *this* question. I'll try to explain better in a custom flag.
- "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"
- What? No, that's not what I'm saying. I guess I'll have to ask in Meta to understand.

Only after asking in Meta, did I discover that the community has decided that an answer includes anything that answers a question that could conceivably be on topic on SO, no matter how irrelevant.

I was confused, because people kept repeating the concepts of "technical inaccuracies" and "wrong answer", neither of which applied to the answer I was flagging. It felt like people were misunderstanding my reason for the flag.

Granted, a bit more careful searching of Meta first would probably have highlighted this to me, but because searching for anything related to NAA has *so many* results, I couldn't reasonably read them all, and none of the ones that I did read seemed to be describing the scenario of an *irrelevant* or *off-topic* answer.

If the decline reason had said something more like:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an **irrelevant or** altogether wrong answer

I'd have learned my mistake from the first decline, saving yet another Meta post and a bunch of mod's time trying to explain it to me. If I was still confused, I'd at least have a more convenient search string for Meta.

I appreciate that this might be a relatively rare case, but it's such a small change that it hardly seems to have any downside, and (IMHO) it makes the canned text more accurately represent the reason for the decline.

Comment: Irrelevant answers are also just wrong answers, the change does not make anything clearer. Let me put it differently: I don't see how this will prevent the common confusion around the flag. The situation is basically this: someone asks about how birds can fly, someone provides an answer about how cats like to hunt birds. Totally irrelevant answer, no doubt about it. Now the question is: is that to be considered an **attempt** to answer or not? There opinions tend to differ. Whether you think yes or no will have a strong influence over your willingness to apply the NAA flag.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that an irrelevant answer is _wrong_. Your example is clearly _correct_, but _irrelevant_, no? Either way, your example (assuming it were about programming not birds and cats) would be declined, and I think it would be an improvement if the decline reason makes it clear why it was declined. Otherwise the flagger is left feeling like the mod has misunderstood the reason for the flag, instead of realising that their understanding of what NAA means is wrong.

Comment: Does that *really* help when a veteran user of 8 years doesn't get it, even after the mod explained it?  The real reason these flags get declined is much more plebeian.  A mod simply can't turn a single flag into a super-vote.  He'll do it once and get no end of grief for not doing it again.  These flags need to be handled by multiple people to be effective.  That doesn't happen anymore, review is broken beyond repair.  The real fix is significantly reducing the workload.  And for you to deal with the bad answer, you have plenty of rep to do so.  A downvote is quite effective.

Comment: Ouch. None taken. As I tried to explain above, I didn't get it because the wording is unclear - the only information I had was "declined because flags aren't for inaccurate or wrong answers". I wasn't flagging an inaccurate or wrong answer, I was flagging an irrelevant answer. Based on my understanding of English that fits the description of the flag. If the decline reason had included the word "irrelevant", I'd have understood immediately. I've no objection to using downvotes, and had already downvoted that answer before being accused of trying to super-downvote with a flag.

Comment: As for significantly reducing the workflow, making decline reasons less ambiguous seems like a free way to do just that. I don't know how much effect it would have, but it would definitely have stopped me flagging a second time, and stopped me asking in meta, so non-zero seems like a reasonable estimate.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave as a side point, the question that heavily inspired you (written by me) to write this proposal was heavily inspired by your experience. Looks like we've gone full circle. Context and perspective are crazy things.

Comment: @Script47 - I did wonder :) For the record, I think your other suggestion of the off-topic answer flag is the better option, but wondered if an even smaller change might be easier to make happen. All 3 suggestions would be nice, of course.

Comment: ....Answers qualifying for NAA should be irrelevant by definition... They just need to be *very* irrelevant. The suggested phrasing would be a terrible change.

Comment: @jpmc26 - do you have an alternative suggestion? Or do you think it's perfect as it is?

Comment: Something similar is being discussed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377539/can-we-add-off-topic-to-the-list-of-answer-flags)

Comment: @sirflipthethird - indeed. I think that's probably the best solution, but I hoped that this was a relatively uncontroversial and very simple change, that could co-exist with that suggestion (albeit with marginally different wording if both were implemented).

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I think it is imperfect as is but that the wording suggested there is actively worse than what we have now. "Do no harm" is a decent motto to work by.

Answer (score 9):

How about we change the text to

```
This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer any question or 
provide supportive information. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another 
question, or deleted altogether.
```

This might help clarify that the "Not an answer" flag is not intended to point out that the answer is not an answer to the question being asked, but instead is intended to point out that the text posted as an answer is not properly posted as an answer but should be posted some other way (or is so useless as to be not worth posting at all).

I think we should also change the flag declination message to something like

```
declined - voting, not flags, should be used to indicate technical 
inaccuracies, irrelevance, or an altogether wrong answer
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I think it's good, I'm just wondering about the "or provide supporting information" bit. I think I'd always assumed that _just_ providing supporting information without addressing the question would be NAA, but I'm learning that I was maybe wrong about that.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, Fundamentally, NAA means "this doesn't belong in an answer box". If you look at [the answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573073/712765) from the wider perspective of SO's mission, which is to provide useful information, I think you will see that the answer is something we would want to preserve. Personally, I would categorize it as a comment rather than an answer, but the way the SO treats comments (presentation, voting, and space limitations) would not do it the justice I think it deserves as a valuable piece of the overall answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Thank you, that all makes good sense, I think with hindsight my approach to a similar answer in future will be to comment suggesting that the OP might like to ask a new, self-answered question with the information answering a more relevant question. I actually did that part-way through the linked discussion, but the comment was deleted for no apparent reason, before the OP had a chance to see it (he'd been active a few hours before, but not since my comment).

Comment: This suggestion would fly in the face of the consensus on everywhere in the network that uses this flag for irrelevant answers.

Comment: @Braiam, the consensus on SO is that irrelevant answers should be downvoted, not flagged for removal by the moderators, because the moderators are not necessarily experts on the topic of the question. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224452/183358) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/712765).

Comment: @OldPro consensus n. *a general agreement*. I don't see that. I see moderators and a group of vocal users twisting what the rest of the network has interpreted correctly: irrelevant answers should be deleted by any means.

Comment: @Braiam: Irrelevant answers should be downvoted, not flagged for removal by the moderators, because the moderators are not necessarily experts on the topic of the question.  Old Pro has it spot on.  He's also right when he says the flag fundamentally means "This doesn't belong in an answer box."  Perhaps we should change the flag's description to *that.*

Comment: Maybe put an extra highlight on  the "any" to drive the point home.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - while I don't necessarily disagree with you, I think Braiam's point is that your use of _should be_ is risky without some evidence of how that's the consensus. If Braiam's right (and I suspect nobody knows) that it's only a small subset of vocal users (and mods) who think that, then it's not really a consensus. I understand the practical difficulties around moderators deciding whether or not an answer is irrelevant, but I'd find it a lot easier to agree if there was some certainty that it's definitely what the community wants. See also: the whole welcoming _thing_... :P

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, I provided a couple of articles for evidence, and those articles link to and have in their "Related" sidebar even more articles that support my and RobertHarvey's assertion. Braiam has provided no counter-evidence. Instead, he decries that he only sees "moderators and a group of vocal users" agreeing. Well, yes, only people that speak up are represented in the conversation. No telling what the silent majority thinks, one way or the other. In an online forum, we can only go by what people who actually participate say.

Comment: I did provide evidence. **No one on the network is discussing this.** The most recent cases of [NAA declined](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4843/41104) the moderator did evaluate context. Now, if it was a moderator of SO, it would have declined on the fact of technical inaccuracies, this moderator read the question and the answer and evaluated that it indeed answers the question. If it wasn't a viable solution, it would have been deleted. (cc @DaveyDaveDave)

Comment: @OldPro - I think the two examples could be read in different ways and I don't think it's right to say they are clear evidence of a consensus. First - the fact that the questions are asked at all suggests an _expectation_ that differs from reality. Second - both have roughly equal (by order of magnitude) numbers of upvotes for the question and the answer. The upvotes on the question _could_ be that people think the question is well-written, or that they are also confused. The upvotes on the answer _could_ be people agreeing that this is the current situation, but not necessarily supporting it.

Comment: I'm playing devil's advocate here, because I do understand why it's not practical for mods to do, BUT I don't think it's fair to declare that there's a consensus, and then (not you, but others) to talk down to anyone asking the question, as if they are a moron for applying plain English the way it's used elsewhere on SE *and* in the whole English-speaking world!

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave, we have [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276197/712765) & [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276759/712765) and [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305798/712765) & [answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/712765) going back 4 years that assert the same thing I'm calling a consensus. We have community-elected moderators (we elect them is so that we can choose people who we trust to implement consensus policies in the absence of clearly established ones) and they agree on this treatment of NAA. Braiam's absence of evidence is not compelling.

Answer (score 3):

There is already a suggested flag declination message, [by Shog:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286366/792066)

> this answer appears to address the asker's problem. Use downvotes to indicate inaccurate or entirely wrong answers. For subtle forms of abuse, choose "other" and explain the problem in detail.

This does exactly what the previous decline message did and suggests a recourse for appealing.

Comment: I did read that post, but I don't think it makes things any clearer. In my case, I'd have been left just as confused, if not more so, because the statement "this answer appears to address the asker's problem" is exactly what I was disagreeing with. That decline reason would convince me even more that the NAA flag was appropriate, and that the mod had misunderstood my reason for flagging.

Comment: I do think including the reference to downvoting is excellent, and should be included if possible. I only didn't include it in my suggestion because I was trying to keep the suggested change as small as possible.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Because it is coupled with a change to the flag text "This was posted as an answer, **but it does not address the problem being asked about**. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether." In which case, it adds that reasoning to the flag, such that the moderator needs to check if it address the problem it's being asked, instead of their current absurd algorithm.

Comment: Ah, OK, I see your point, but that would mean changing the apparent consensus that an answer doesn't need to address the problem being asked about. I agree with you that it's absurd, but from my previous question, I gather that it's a long-established consensus that's unlikely to change. Given that, it seems only reasonable that the text of the decline reason should match the reality of what's consider flag-worthy. And surely adding 2 words to the reason is much more feasible than changing that consensus?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave such "consensus" is only on Stack Overflow and not even shared by everyone. Basically, that is only the most vocal POV. It wasn't originally there. Nothing on the documentation argues that such answers doesn't need to be deleted or restricts moderators ability to do so. I'm member in at least 5 other sites, and I assure you, that if in Gaming.SE you post a Mario party answer to a Dwarf Fortress question, it will get flagged and deleted.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you at all, but if that's how moderators are working (and it seems that it is) then surely matching the decline message to the facts makes sense?

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I prefer changing the behavior rather than adjusting to it. Remember, this message is used elsewhere in the network, and it shall be adjusted to what the network does, not what SO moderators decided to.