# Deleted comments

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, deleted-comments

Earlier today, I left a couple of comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26976806/372643) pointing out a couple of security problems with what this user was doing. They seem to have been deleted.

Any idea why? Was it automatic?

Comment: Do you remember what they were? Only mods can see deleted comments...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I can't remember the exact wording, but I was pointing to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643) explaining why using 0 for VERIFYPEER/VERIFYHOST is a bad idea. I was also pointing out that pasting your private key into a website isn't a good idea either (since private keys are meant to be private...).

Comment: Was the comment chain long? Sometimes a mod will come through and just nuke everything if it appears off-topic.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Just two comments really (which could probably have fitted into one). I'm not sure if anyone left any comments after that.

Comment: Both the comments were flagged as not constructive, *twice* each. The moderator deleted them. *<insert general spiel about "they're just comments and are subject to deletion on a whim" here>* I doubt much thought was put into it.

Comment: @animuson Ah OK, I can't remember the wording, maybe it wasn't clear enough, or maybe some people consider drawing attention to more general security problems as not constructive...

Comment: Wondering when "comments as 2nd class" means "they should be ephemeral" will be reconsidered. Seems fair that they aren't as important as questions or answers, but to deem them valueless flies in the face of the facts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are second class citizens.  They're subject to deletion at any time, for any reason.

In this case, someone (I don't know who) flagged them as 'not constructive'.  I deleted them.

[image]

Revisiting it, I've undeleted them.

In the future, if you want to be sure what you say stays around, post it as an answer.

In this case, while not a complete answer; [posting an answer comprised of those two comments  would be a good idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer): It addresses the question; gives good information about what would be an issue with what the user is doing, and provides durability that otherwise might not be there with a comment. When the OP responds, it can always be edited to include a more complete answer.

In the past, I've seen instances where OPs flag any comments they deem 'negative' on their question (for instance, comments that address security concerns).  I don't know whether that was the case here (as I don't know who flagged the comments and why), but I do know that some nefarious users try to get us to delete negative comments on their questions.  When we see clearly that's what is going on, we'll decline those.

We don't always catch it -- as I did not catch it in this instance.

I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Those comment in no way even *attempt* to answer the question.  Posting them as an answer would be entirely inappropriate.  If it were an answer it could very well be deleted for not being an attempt to answer the question.  It's not okay to post a comment as an answer just because you think that the comment is important or shouldn't be deleted.

Comment: @Servy I disagree about it not addressing the question. It does do that. "Don't do X or Y" when the user asks about X is addressing the question.   Whether it's the best answer in the world is another story -- but, as a moderator, I would not delete an answer that contained the information his comments contained.

Comment: I didn't say it didn't address the question.  I said it doesn't **answer** the question.  An answer needs to *answer the question* not just address the question.  Clarifying questions address the question too, but they're not acceptable answers.  If he posted the contents of those comments as an answer then it would meet the textbook definition of NAA and you *should* delete it as a moderator.  You not deleting that as an answer is just as wrong as you deleting it as a comment.

Comment: @Servy It's ok that we disagree.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker No, it's not.  You're advocating that people post answers that should be deleted, and that are very likely to end up being deleted by other people.  You're also saying that answers to which SE's guidelines make it crystal clear warrant deletion shouldn't be deleted.  Every single person that has their NAA posts deleted could reference this as justification for why their post shouldn't be deleted.  You are perfectly within your rights to think that this would make a good post, as that's subjective.  But what you can't do is advocate violating the rules, especially as a moderator.

Comment: This is why I rarely deleted "not constructive" flagged comments.  They're all "not constructive."  Things I don't miss about being a mod...

Comment: @Will DELETE THEM ALL!!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/is-dont-do-it-a-valid-answer George @Servy

Comment: That answers *answer the question* rather than *address the question* is one of the key differences between Stack Overflow and forums. To suggest having comments that are "this is a bad idea because of XYZ" but doesn't actually solve the problem being asked in the question is a step in the direction of making SO a forum. Furthermore, suggesting that down (and up) votes will sort them out is not sufficient when poor quality answers have dozens of upvotes in many situations (making them only delectable by a mod... and, well, [yeah...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/289086)).

Comment: @Servy If you think our criteria should be different than what is laid out in the meta-SE question I link to in my answer; please open a new meta-SO question on the subject.

Comment: My [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981440/using-a-database-query-result#comment42497358_26981440) of "I am compelled to point out that `stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM UserStocks WHERE userID = '"+userID+"' ORDER BY symbol");` has a gaping wide open SQL injection possibility." does ***not*** answer the question being asked and should ***not*** be an answer, but I would contend *is* an important comment and something that people looking at the question should be aware of if they are trying to use it to answer their own question in the future.

Comment: @MichaelT (see my above comment to servy).  It's better if we have this discussion in the context of an actual meta post instead of having the discussion in the comments.

Comment: @Servy unless you (or George) wants to frame the question in a particular way, I'd be happy to start off the question on meta.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm not advocating a chance in SE policy.  I'm stating that your answer conflicts with SE's policy, so I have no reason to create a new question about changing a policy that I don't see a reason to change.  I'm specifically discussion the application of established policy to this specific case here.  I would also like my previous comment restored (whether you care to respond to it or not), as it is very much addressing that point.

Comment: @Servy (and auto ping George) - [What constitutes an answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277048/289086)

Comment: ... @Servy you should have posted it as an answer that addresses the question. {/snark}

Comment: @MichaelT /bow.

Comment: I must say I wasn't expecting such a long comment thread on meta for this tiny issue ;-). George, no need to apologise, if anything, I'd question the users who've flagged it... I just commented at the time because I didn't really have the time to write a full answer (I've written a bit more in an answer now). To be honest, I've written hundreds (literally) of answers on the `ssl` tag, many of them about *not* bypassing certificate validation, I wasn't particularly after rep points, was afraid of repeating myself about cert validation, and didn't have time to try that particular use case...