# Should comments be auto-deleted (from Stack Exchange podcast #61)

Tags: discussion, comments

[Podcast #61 – The “What Jay’s Done Wrong”](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/11/podcast-61-the-what-jays-done-wrong-podcast/?cb=1) have following remark:

> Should comments stick around forever, or disappear after 21 days? I bet you can guess Joel’s opinion.

I think it will be a significant loss for the sites if there is a decision to expire all comments after a period of time.

Why to keep comments forever:

- Adding comments to a good answer is a cheap way to add information quickly. If someone decides it needs to go into an answer and have time to do it nicely - a comment can be marked manually for deletion.
- Editing code in posts is generally discouraged, so code fixes are generally suggested as comments.
- Link-only answers are discouraged - so a comment is the right way to point to some link. That is, an answer is directly present in some standard document or existing external site.

Why to auto-remove:

- Comments are temporary anyway
- Comments should be edited into answers/questions
- Most of comments have no lasting value (like "clarify your question").

---

Notes

- There is a somewhat unrelated old discussion in *[Allow for setting comments to "auto-expire", to become "temporary comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/allow-for-setting-comments-to-auto-expire-to-become-temporary-comments)*, which would let one opt in into auto-expiration.
- There were requests for "convert comment to answer" which never turned into a real feature. It is somewhat covered in discussion [if it is OK to convert someone else comment into and answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269913/comment-poaching).

Comment: Joel may be in favour, but you can hear Jay and David are already pushing back on it in the podcast. For good reason! You don't want comments on highly-upvoted answers that are wrong *today* to be lost, because it'll take a while to downvote those answers.

Comment: So I am not sure why we need to have a discussion on this at all, really.

Comment: The *'comments should be temporary'*-idea just doesn't work in the real world; nor should they all be edits; for example, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071339/how-can-i-fix-my-functions-in-bash#comment42655489_27071339) provides useful information to the OP (IMHO), but should not be an Answer; you don't want to auto-delete it, since there's no way of knowing if the the OP has read it (or he/she may want to refer to it later).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't need discussion on it as I already made up my mind :) (also with good arguments I can change my opinion too)... But I think it may be useful to have some recorded feedback whether people think one way or another.

Comment: Just put it this way: Joel has voiced *loads* of hair-brained ideas on the podcast, which then quickly get shut down *during the cast*. I'd not put too much value on his comments in that respect. :-P

Comment: related: [Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180325/165773) at MSE and [Comments without upvotes are now hidden if a question has more than two answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2899/168) at Workplace meta

Comment: A few days ago it was suggested that we make it easier to flag/delete comments

Comment: @Coffee Really we just need non-mods to have a (practical) way to delete comments that aren't extremely offensive or spam.  As it stands, comments that are obsolete, offtopic, chatty, etc. require moderator intervention, whey they simply shouldn't.

Comment: @Servy - Agreed , agreed.  I'll chew on this idea a bit, but I think part of complication is that comment-flags are lumped into "general-flags" bin. I'm not a mod or 3000+ rep so it's hard for me to comment. But perhaps if comment flags were divorced from "general-flags" and auto-removed after some number of flags. Some ideas, I guess

Comment: @Coffee They're not intermingled; they have their own queue.

Comment: @Servy - Hmm,  I see. And that queue is available only to 10,000+ rep users? That would mean it's only visible to < 1% of all users ... which yea, maybe the doors can be widened a little. If it was available to more , that would seem like easiest workaround. though admittedly that is maybe a temporary fix

Comment: @Coffee No, it's a mod only queue, 10k users don't have access to it.

Comment: @Servy - Wow , that's interesting. Yeah... certainly alot of work for mods then.   I will scratch my head on it... I think If Joel is commenting on comments it must be a problem !

Comment: Perhaps the simplest modification may be to authorize any arbitrary user mod-privileges with regards to comments *within* their own posts. I.E if I ask a question, allow me to rule the comment-domain inside my own question. Or ... perhaps , that's too much power?  I dunno... if we all agree that comments are "2nd-class", well.. giving that power *is* what  2nd-class means.

Comment: But i know...  that  inertia - "why are we worrying about silly comments !!!!"

Comment: @Coffee People shouldn't be able to go around deleting all of the comments explaining why their answer is wrong, or what all of the problems with their question are (and you know *lots* of people would).  It would remove one of the primary purposes of comments.

Comment: @Servy - Touche, touche.. that is true; it would certainly open the door for abuse like that. Hmm, I will keep thinking on it through the day.

Comment: @Servy there's a MSE feature request from awhile back suggesting how to offload more of the comment flagging to 10k: [Make comment flagging work more like chat flagging, available to users with 10k reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138149/213963)

Comment: @Coffee if you look at [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277031/deleted-comments) you will see issue already with owners flagging comments pointing out problems with the question.  Doing it without *some* oversight would open up *many* more of such issues raised on meta.

Comment: There was an interesting comment down on that blog page , however -  `The goal is really to clean out the rubbish without losing the value-adding content, so how do we do that? Actually, you already have a metric you cold use for that: votes provide us with a very good indication of how valuable a comment is. However, it can take time to accrue votes.

So here is my proposal: Autodelete any comment which has less than 1 up-vote per month (for example.)`   I would change the rule to `less than 1 up-vote, and checked once after a year` (i.e only remove comments  with 0 votes, after a year

Comment: Reason being, *even if* some brilliant comment lasts one whole year without an upvote, it's still an unnoticed comment.   X

Comment: @MichaelT - That's true,  it gives *too much* power to the user. will rethink, thanks !

Comment: @Coffee Votes represent opinions only of SE users with 15 reputation, which are a small part of the audience. The majority of people reading and benefiting from the content posted on these sites cannot vote, as they do not have an account.

Comment: The whole "comments are temporary" thing is a mad myth peddled by mad people in a mad fantasy land. It has no basis in reality, thankfully.

Comment: Just make the future comments disappear, the old ones can stay, this way a slow transition can be made. If a comment is ready for deletion the author is reminded if he/she wishes to update them in an answer or question or make a new answer with them.

Answer (score 7):

I answered a similar question on meta.SE [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240501/comments-should-only-persist-on-questions-answers-for-48-hours/240506#240506)

The main points

> While I'm a big fan of deleting/flagging comments, I see lots of value
>   in comments many times. So I don't think auto-removing every comment
>   after 48 hours or 2 months for that matter is the right thing to do.
>
> What I would propose instead is one or all of these processes being
>   implemented:
>
> 1. The team should run their own queries deleting comments, *that are 99% likely to be useless*, at least every couple months.
> 2. The team should add *if conditions* in the flagging, so many more comments are eligible for auto-deletion on one user flag.
> 3. The team should make many more words/phrases that are contained in a comment eligible for one flag deletion.

Comment: Point two is already implemented, there are several comments that can be deleted with a single flag

Comment: @Braiam there's only 1 nuke phrase that uses if condition,that i'm aware of. The other nuke words/phrases can be any number of characters long, etc. What I mean by that one, is that thank you, thanks, etc, should definitely be nuke words, **if** the comment is less than say 20 characters

Answer (score 4):

Alternative proposal:

Existing comments are grandfathered in, since they were written in the belief that they would only be deleted if flagged, deemed irrelevant by a mod, etc.

New comments will be deleted after a fixed period, and must be written with that in mind.

Therefore, for example, if I come across an old answer that I think needs some caveat, I would become more likely to edit it to fix it myself rather than leaving a note. And also more likely to do nothing at all, of course, since editing is more effort than commenting. The reason being, at the moment I can comment because I know future visitors to the answer can see the warning, and it's perhaps more polite to give the original author the opportunity to edit as they prefer rather than as I think best. By making comments truly temporary, the etiquette changes since I simply don't know that my comments will be seen by future readers or the author. I must either edit or do nothing.

Similarly, if a fresh answer is close but not correct, currently I comment with a correction. If comments were truly temporary then I would more likely either edit, or else comment with a correction *and downvote*, just in case my comment is ignored and then vanishes. Currently the comment mitigates the minor error to the extent it's not deserving of a downvote, but an error that future readers aren't warned about probably does deserve downvoting.

Personally, I'm much less troubled by comments than consensus seems to be (especially mods), but I can't downvote my own answer even on meta.

Answer (score -5):

Allow the author to control the comment's permanence. (The commenter probably knows best.) Comments should be temporary by default. [image: Comments]

Comment: Related [feature request for temporary comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320552/burn-after-reading-comment)