# Auto-expire transitory comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

(This is not a proposal to auto-expire all comments. [That has been there before.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/should-comments-be-auto-deleted-from-stack-exchange-podcast-61))

Often, comments are transitory in nature, such as:

> On Stack Overflow we don't say "Hi", "Thanks", ...
>
> Please shorten the code in this question.
>
> Why is this being downvoted? The question is very basic but it is valid.

It would be entirely sufficient to keep these comments for a few days until all relevant parties have seen them. They are about process, not about content. **They have no lasting value.**

**We do need comments like these.** We cannot simply forbid them. We also don't want mods to spend time cleaning them up.

We should have a facility to **mark comments as transitory. This would cause them to disappear after a day or so.** The comment author should be able to **mark his own comment** when posting it. This is not about marking other user's comments.

When the site detects that a comment about to be posted is likely to be transitory in nature it should visually recommend to mark the comment. Automatically detecting likely transitory comments should be doable. [It should be possible to train a spam filter on this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280546/can-a-machine-be-taught-to-flag-comments-automatically?lq=1) After a month of this feature there will be a huge corpus to train on.

What do you think of this? Is it useful?

Comment: I like it. I mark it as transitory, and I don't have to remember to delete it when its obviously obsolete. Might make the "Resolution" hat hard to get though ;)

Comment: Duplicate MSE feature request: [Allow for setting comments to “auto-expire”, to become “temporary comments”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7738/allow-for-setting-comments-to-auto-expire-to-become-temporary-comments) (and check the "Linked" section of that question - it has been requested numerous times there in different forms)

Comment: What's to stop people abusing the feature by marking good comments as transitory? Do we mark our own comments as transitory or other people's?

Comment: @MattCoubrough any example? Why would anyone expire their own "good" comment? (One could only mark their own comments. Not comments made by others.)

Comment: @usr That clarifies it thanks, I was imagining people marking other comments they stumbled upon as transitory! But being able to mark *my own comments* in that manner seems like a good idea.

Comment: And what about *subsequent* comments that were made in reply to the (now expired) transitory comments? Pseudo-intelligent automation is going to make Swiss cheese of a once-normal conversation. I don't think automating the cleanup will take care of the inherent problems of our comment system. I've been rethinking comments from the ground up — why people use them and how they *should* be managed. But I don't think vigilant maintenance (even automated) is the solution to the comment "problem." The  solution is comment-like system that doesn't get unruly in the first place.

Comment: There should be no need to manually mark comments as transitory. As Andy has showed with flagging, this level of logic is well in reach of todays Machine Learning techniques. Just go ahead, train the system and then mark those comments automatically.

Comment: People use comments for conversation, humor, and everything but what SE originally intended for comments, even though it's usually related to the topic at hand, if not the author's intelligence or that of their parents or dog. I say we change "add a comment" to "visit chat".

Comment: @RobertCartaino : Anyway, a commenter can later remove manually a comment because he thinks it is no longer relevant making the swiss cheese. Provided temporary comments are identifiable, it would be other commenters responsability not to leave a permanent comment to a transitory one. I do not really like the idea of an automated process in charge to guess what writer really thought ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta And what is the UI element that says "this is a transitory comment; do not reply"? This has to be usable by the average user, not just the diehards who read these meta discussions.

Comment: @RobertCartaino : There are indeed 2 categories of users, some that cares about making SO clean, and others that do not. I think that those *don't care* users will continue to do as they currently do. This would be an advanced feature for  users interested in SO quality (those that leave most answers and comments) to help them to have comments that will vanish when no longer useful. It is no use to hope a magic and perfect solution. The only question is : will it be better or worse ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta In my view, a more complicated system that doesn't solve the problem = "worse".

Comment: @usr : you already have  an`obsolete`option when flagging comments.

Comment: @user2284570 this is about self-flagging comments. Not flagging comments of others.

Answer (score 5):

The interesting challenge here is whether we can classify the comments well enough that we can link them to the actual suggested action. Can we automatically expire comments that have been resolved?

For instance, comments about `thank.*` can be removed if the last line of the text no longer contains `"Thank you"`.

More complex, comments that suggest specific edits on a closed question can probably be expired if the question is and stays reopened (Don't expire them immediately on reopening)

Answer (score -2):

Why would you not be able to mark other people's comments as "flagged for expiry"? Then after a few agreement votes, we can get rid of the comment.

This would deal with the classic:

> **Me:** You should mention this other thing
>
> **You:** Agreed. I've updated my answer.

You could then flag both of our comments for expiry and I can say "yes, fine."

Comment: This is already there. You can delete your own comments and flag others' as "obsolete".

Answer (score -8):

I was going to post the same before seeing you did it first.

My only suggestion is to keep it simple. I believe the core function of being able to mark your own comment to expire after a set time would be incredibly useful for the purpose of reducing the workload of those who go clean them up.

However, additional behaviors like AI that recommends you do it becomes a source of debate that probably impedes acceptance; and this kind of thing can always be added later if it's thought to be worthwhile.

I also hate that SO says I can't say "Thanks". I do anyway... I just add the required additional characters. I'm not a freaking robot; when someone just helped me out, I'm going to say thanks. I'm a human being, and that's what human beings do. So I think SO needs to just get over that fact and stop trying to impose SEO requirements (or whatever the source for this rule is) on us to stop being humans. This would be a great solution for such comments, and of course also for the many transitory comments which are much more legitimate in the moment.

Comment: Last paragraph: Users can express their thanks by upvoting the content they're thankful for. As SO is meant to be a repository of quality Q&A, "Thanks" comments are considered noise, and should be removed.

Comment: I also find saying thanks necessary. An upvote could come from anyone. There needs to be a social acknowledgment from the OP. A transitory comment would be a great way to do that. Currently, you kind of have to break the rules and rely on comment deletion. This creates unnecessary work for the mods, so it's not ideal.

Comment: Well, see @usr, some day when they rack up enough points they'll be able to go back through all their questions and see who did the upvoting so that's already been covered too, right? :)

Comment: @BVernon Well, they can't see who voted. I gave over 5000 answers and I really found it nice to know that the OP cared about my efforts. That means more than approving of my solution with a green checkmark. From that experience, I always comment on essentially all answers just to let them know.

Comment: @usr Ah, I thought I had seen a post many years ago where people with enough rep were investigating some malicious user and could see his down votes. In any case, I was obviously being facetious. I'm the same way; I don't always comment but if someone has clearly put effort into helping me I definitely do.

Answer (score -22):

If your comment is so transitory that you know it will soon be useless anyway, please don't make it in the first place. Comments were meant to be ephemeral, but not *that* ephemeral. The system is designed to catch little bits of *useful* feedback such as requests for clarification or suggestions form improvement. Please reserve it for comments which serve those purposes. If you use it for things which don't serve these purposes, you dilute the concentration and take the focus away from the places where those things *are* happening.

This sort or system would only encourage *more noise*. It would create a culture where "+1 thanks" comments are expected. That would quickly erode the high signal-to-noise ratio that attracted most of the expertise to Stack Exchange in the first place.

Re examples:

> On Stack Overflow we don't say "Hi", "Thanks", ...

This is easily said in an edit comment. If people are ignoring the ways their posts are being edited and not learning from them, then temporary comments aren't going to fix it either. Either they learn from their mistakes when they get corrected or they don't, in which case you need stronger sauce.

> Please shorten the code in this question.

Depending on content, this is a marginally useful comment. Why shorten? If this is a request to fix something in a question, it shouldn't be obsoleted until the problem is addressed. It should also be more specific and explain what the actual issue is. At that point this would be a normal comment of the sort that the function was designed for and there is no need for an extra "temporary" feature. Lacking actual specifics, this comment is pretty useless is general and better not made.

> Why is this being downvoted?

Comments asking about downvotes are almost never constructive. Making them temporary wouldn't  make them any more useful. Better to discourage them entirely.

Comment: There are valid comments that are transitory. See the examples. In fact I don't see what's so harmful about thanking someone in a transitory comment. It creates no lasting damage.

Comment: I somewhat agree with this point - while the featur will make cleaning up comments easier, it will also make it easier for someone to leave noisy chit-chat comments.  Sure the chit-chat comment will get deleted in the long term, in the short term you may have more garbage to sort through to find valid comments

Comment: Re _«It creates no lasting damage.»_ Why would we allow it to do temporary damage?

Comment: @Caleb because it gives us a lot more benefit elsewhere.

Comment: Note that truly useless comments can still be flagged. Perhaps we could have a (somewhat low) rep threshold for activating this feature, so the user *knows* what comments are for?

Comment: "easily said in an edit comment" -- approximately no one reads the edit summaries, not even edit reviewers (who really should).  Newbies on the receiving end of a "hi, thanks" removal won't even know edit summaries are a thing.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Then rather than hijacking a mechanism to stand in for it, maybe the solution would be to make the existing correct feature more visible. (Also my experience is that new users _do_ tend to  read those messages as they show up in their inbox. They are confused about what to do about it because the edit history is a new interface for them, but they often figure it out. Reviewers is another problem, they have issues!)

Comment: Clarifications comments are transitory by nature and can be forgotten by their author. Asking "What exactly you mean by X?" in comment should eventually be useless. Same goes for the many responses to those. Why not add a simple feature to clean those up?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The problem is the author ---doesn't always--- rarely is going to know when they would expire. Rather the one editing the post to fix the problem or observing later that it has been cleaned up is going to know when a previous comment is obsolete. Observation is much more reliable than prediction—which brings us to the "why not": because it will add complexity and confusion without actually _solving_ the problem.

Comment: Actually, I know when I want some of my comments to expire. When I was reviewing more, I often wanted to warn some editors that their edits could use more work and the only way was to make a comment to them that had nothing to do with the questions/answer they edited, which I then had to delete myself. If I could have made them transitory it would have saved me to remember to delete them.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I would suggest that is jury-rigging something on the comment system for which it wasn't designed in the first place. Rather than try to patch the comment system to handle such cases why not suggest a proper edit-review feedback mechanism?