# How does SO handle permalink to a comment after a large number of comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

Given a permalink to a comment, [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow?lq=1#comment809136_180325), the whole comment thread is expanded if necessary.

What if the comment permalink points to a comment which comes after, say 1,000, comments? Do the large amount of comments still get expanded?

Comment: I hope someone starts purging comments after more than, say, 10 were on a post. It's not very likely you'll find a situation like this on the network.

Comment: At the moment, there are over [250k posts with more than 10 comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/114449/count-of-posts-where-more-than-10-comments). I do not think anyone would want to clean those.

Comment: The large amount of comments still gets expanded. While I think 1000 is a bit exaggerated, I feel like I've seen posts with over 100 comments that I used the link to one of the last few comments to keep the chain expanded and see if anything new popped up.

Comment: That's not my point. It'll still work for [148 comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights/18746930#comment50313108_18746930) and when we end up with more, we'll see, right? :)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, there is no pagination for comments, there are only collapsed and all comments states. Is this correct? The linear permalink overhead could be avoided by pagination.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, assuming `loadAllComments`, which does an ajax call to get all the comments, doesn't timeout.

Answer (score 8):

> If I'm not wrong, there is no pagination for comments, there are only collapsed and all comments states. Is this correct? The linear permalink overhead could be avoided by pagination.

By the time you have so many comments, there's something wrong. Comments are temporary in nature. There should not be that many, so navigation and performance are a non-issue in that regard IMHO.

Comment: @Richard they are _meant_ to be temporary. If you see differently, that's a different problem. See [What are comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Comment: @Richard you're not _expected to_, but I do it sometimes - and flag comments as obsolete if the issue mentioned therein has been integrated in the posts. See [Auto-expire transitory comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280672/auto-expire-transitory-comments) for a proposal that lets comments be automatically removed after a period of time. :)

Comment: Well that's my new thing for the day learnt - I can relax now for the rest of it.