# What's the logic behind comment selection when there are many comments?

Tags: support, comments

What query is used to show the 'popular' comments when the number of comments is too many?

Comment: Highest voted comments and order of comments. If there are not enough highly voted (and newer) comments, it's just later comments that are hidden. As later comments become upvoted, they push older comments into the "hidden" area.

Comment: Another related question (that I would like to know) is about the logic behind *how many* comments will appear. There are questions where just a few comments are visible and others with many many comments.

Comment: As Zanon mentioned, the current algorithm does not select a fixed number of comments. This is not good for all posts, sometimes an answer is buried below 15 comments. What @Kendra described sounds like an ill posed version of decay ranking algorithm, a good example is [reddit's ranking algorithm](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588). If the decay ranking method was properly implemented for comments, each comment would have had a popularity score, then we could easily select a fixed the top N popular comments for the time.

Comment: _"sometimes an answer is buried below 15 comments"_ Once again, this is why people should not write answers in comments. **Answers go in answers.** Why are people not getting this -.-

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant the actual answer post is well below the question post, spaced by 15 comments. So a google user who lands on that question page has to scroll down to see the answer.

Comment: @ali: Oh, well sorry. That doesn't seem like a terrible hardship, though. Oh no, a Google user landed on the question page and had to _scroll_ by 300 or so additional pixels in order to get their immediate free expert help. Can't say I'll lose any sleep over that!!

Comment: Like [your previous question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298367/how-does-so-handle-permalink-to-a-comment-after-a-large-number-of-comments): _why_ are you so interested in this, why are you placing this emphasis on comments? Comments on Stack Overflow are not meant to be long-lived. See also @Lightness's comment and [How do comments work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [What are comments?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm interested in this because it seems to me that [comments business logic in SO is not well defined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325). Comments were not originally part of the Q&A design of SO, then they were introduced to solve the question clarification problem, and they ended up to be one of those solutions that generate more problems.  I'm not against comments, I'm just trying to understand the ambiguous borders of this feature in SO.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how this question and its answers will address that "problem", or whether it's just here to satisfy your own curiosity.

Comment: @CodeCaster here is the chain: **lack of question clarification feature → introduce comments → too many comments causing noise → only show a selection by default → what's the algorithm for this selection?** The way the selection works currently leads to yet another problem: when clicking on show more comments, the old thread is replaced by a new thread which has a different sorting. The user loses the reference of the comment she already went through.

Comment: Then we're back to my answer on your previous question: comments are meant to ask for clarification (for which they are great), not discussion. If there are too many comments, we should focus on that (i.e. instruct users to edit their posts instead of adding more comments) instead of making the comments easier to navigate. The point is: as a question visitor, you should not have to read comments. If there currently are a lot of posts with too many comments that contain answers (as opposed to the post itself), then **that** is the problem that needs fixing, not the comment count.

Comment: @CodeCaster you are assuming that people can get to a _clarification_ without going throw a _discussion_. There is no guarantee that this can be the case all the time. And when this does happen, it is not reasonable to ask users to clean up the discussion related comments, just because they are supposed to be ephemeral. Look at _this_ very thread. You [started](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298371?noredirect=1#comment215760_298371) with clarification, and now you are into a discussion with me. Are you going to delete those comments later?

Comment: This is meta. I'm talking about the regular site. If a question on the regular site needs lots of discussion in order to be answered, it's most likely not a good question as we'd like to see them on the site, and perhaps someone should then invite OP to chat, for example - and close the question. I think you're seeing problems that don't exist, or looking for the wrong solution if it already were a problem.

Comment: As illustrated here, sometimes the comments shed useful light on the topic. Sometimes that can be edited back into the question or answer; sometimes it can't; often it isn't. HOWEVER, I don't think having to click "show the rest" is a hardship... and I would hope that before comments are discarded someone _does_ make an effort to scavenge them and either edit locally or start a new question for those points. HOWEVER AGAIN,, I'm not sure how often anyone actually makes that effort. HOWEVER YET AGAIN, if they don't we usually haven't lost anything completely unrecoverable. It works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

For what it has been my experience, it simply select the 5 comments with more upticks (upvotes?) and shows them. If more than one have the same amount of upticks it shows the newest first. That's the only logic here. (meta is different, of course)

Other sites may have different preferences, like showing no comments at all unless they have some upticks ([Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2899/9787)).

Comment: It actually shows the oldest first (given an equal number of upvotes). Are you saying this should change?

Comment: @MrLister no, OP is asking what's the logic to show popular comments on a post. I'm describing that.