# Burn after reading comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

Sometimes I want/have to leave comments like "Thank you so much!" and "Answer edited, better now?" to notify someone. I don't think such comments will be helpful to others viewing posts.

So I think it would be nice if there is something like a "Burn after reading comment", that is, the comment is automatically deleted after the user I @ed has read it.

Comment: What REAL benefit to the site does this bring? This'll just end up being abused, sending "self-destructing" insults. I see no benefit that the current behavior of the site cannot handle

Comment: @Patrice Then what about comments that are only visible to a certain user?

Comment: Again... why? And THIS would be even more prone to abuse. I don't see the benefits. Instead of trying to change your FR, try to see what problem you're trying to address

Comment: Do you mean like the flag as obsolete option that already exists?

Comment: @Patrice I think some comments are unnecessary, thus should be hidden. Perhaps a better folding algorithm can be helpful?

Comment: Also - how do you ensure a user has read a comment?

Comment: unnecessary? yes, maybe. Problematic? no. Should we create a new system to make them invisible when both you and the @ed can flag as obsolete, which is WELL on its way to being auto-deleted? I don't think it's worth it

Comment: Welcome to SnapOverflow

Answer (score 12):

Flag the obsolete/unconstructive/chatty comments and a moderator will delete them.  Or if the comments are yours, just delete them yourself.  Mission Impossible comments aren't useful.

Why should a comment be self-deleting?  If I were the other user you pinged, I might want the "temporary" comment to not delete itself so that I could further clarify things.  Or edit it into a post.