# Add a character that enables immediate comment removal via obsolete flag

Tags: feature-request, comments

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320553/2808510) suggests self-deleting comments. This implementation seems like a bad idea all round - and the answer was fairly unsatisfactory to me:

> Flag the obsolete/unconstructive/chatty comments and a moderator will delete them. Or if the comments are yours, just delete them yourself. Mission Impossible comments aren't useful.

This seems to be making extra, unnecessary work for the moderators.

So, I propose a character or phrase that could be included in a comment that allows an "obsolete" flag to take effect immediately, similar to the spam / offensive flag with swear words.

It's not uncommon that I want to tell someone something - not necessarily "Thanks", but sometimes, "I'll try that, ping me later" or "@user I've edited the answer, check now".

Allowing other people to remove that comment saves the moderators time, and cleans up the site - and this word or character would do that.

I'd suggest |, an ASCII character that does have some uses - but is not used frequently. It's present on UK and US keyboard layouts, and as it's ASCII should render on any machine.

Comment: I don't see the benefit.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's not uncommon that I want to tell someone something - not necessarily "Thanks", but sometimes, "I'll try that, ping me later" or "@user I've edited the answer, check now". Allowing other people to remove that comment saves the moderators time.

Comment: Like... "Thank you very much for this answer. accept rate"

Comment: @404 Yes, that's another example.

Comment: Using | for the self-delete character would annoy anyone who provides C || regex answers in comments.  (Some might consider that an upside.)

Comment: @PetahChristian :) This is not a self delete / self destruct - this is an "other users can remove it"... I can image this being abused, minimally. As you say - only more advanced users would know about it.

Comment: @Tim: "*It's not uncommon that I want to tell someone something*" If you want to chat with someone, take it to chat. You should not use comments for this sort of thing, period.

Comment: @NicolBolas I didn't say chat. I said tell someone something... What are comments for if not communication? You seemed to ignore the next part of my sentence "*"I'll try that, ping me later" or "@user I've edited the answer, check now"*" - should that be reserved for chat - I disagree if you think so.

Comment: @Tim: "*I didn't say chat. I said tell someone something...*" Telling someone something like "I'll try that, ping me later", something that is useful only to that person and yourself, is not what comments are for. Requesting more information is useful to everyone (since we can see that someone has asked for that info and therefore do not need to request it ourselves). But something like "I'll try that", is for chat, not comments.

Comment: @Tim: "I've edited the answer" is useful to more people, as a notice that the answer may have changed since it was last seen. But there's no need to be able to auto-delete such comments.

Comment: @NicolBolas I disagree completely. Telling someone that you have noted their suggestions - e.g. in response to another comment - is sensible and polite. Maybe this is because I use another site a lot. On Ask Ubuntu, comments are used significantly to debug, and help others. Re: "there's no need to be able to auto-delete such comments" - there's no need for them to stay either. They're directed at one person only - the person you're assisting. Any future visitors will not need to know there was an old revision. Again, perhaps this difference is because I use Ask Ubuntu a lot.

Comment: @Tim: "*On Ask Ubuntu, comments are used significantly to debug, and help others.*" That would suggest that such comments contain *useful information*, which would be useful for anyone who has that problem. And therefore, deleting them is the wrong thing to do. Such information should be moved into the answer itself. But simply saying "I'll try that" is not useful information. You don't need to inform people that you have noted their suggestions. You need to inform them if the suggestion worked (accept the answer) or if it didn't (comment about the failure).

Comment: @NicolBolas I would still disagree - back and forth clarifying command output is of very little use to anyone. To that extent, I have a self-destruct app that removes my comments after a certain time period. Nobody seems to miss them.

Answer (score 1):

Only a few people would likely be aware of that 'magic phrase' to automatically delete a comment, making it of limited use.  Others who inadvertently used it might find their comment unexpectedly deleted.

A feature like you proposed would more likely be prone to misuse by people sending rude comments that self-deleted, [as Patrice mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320552/burn-after-reading-comment/320553#comment330768_320552). That would make it *more* difficult to moderate the site in general.

Considering the likely number of duplicate meta-questions or comments from users asking or complaining about disappearing comments, it would possibly create **more** comments or work than it automatically saved.

*Making the magic phrase more obscure would just make it harder to use, considering that something short and easy like [mcve] can inadvertently be remembered as [mvce].*

Comment: What about the character ¬ or | ? Just like ` is used to allow multiple @pings.

Comment: I'll think about that and get back to you. 

Comment: Can you not see the characters I suggested? The second is part of ASCII, and on both UK and US keyboard layouts... The first seems to be UK only, so that's a bad suggestion.