# Using NAA on jokes that make no attempt to answer the question

Tags: discussion, support, not-an-answer

According to every post I've read on the subject, be it on the SE meta, or on this meta, Not an Answer flags are limited strictly to answers which don't even look like an answer.

And yet, when I flagged this joke:

> Pseudocode:
>
> ```
> function GetFifthElement(LinkedList list) {
>     return ; }
> ```

[Link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305348/c-sharp-return-the-fifth-element-from-the-tail-or-end-of-a-singly-linked-lis/8305532#8305532) (from Nov. 2011)

Not only was the flag disputed, it accrued 4 up-votes (28 to 32).

While I am aware that things were different the four years ago this answer was created, I had thought that such did not qualify as an answer in this current era.

Am I wrong?

Comment: It is *an* attempt to answer *a* question even if it is a joke. The proper response would be to downvote if you think it isn't useful. If you really really want to flag it, then flag it for moderator attention and let them know that We Hate Fun™ and you don't think that a joke is an appropriate response to the question. I would not suggest doing that because it's a waste of moderator time, and you will probably get a declined flag.

Comment: @TinyGiant Done.  And the question was basically 'how to get the fifth element of an array', with no work or tries shown.  Still, I didn't think this would not qualify as NAA.

Comment: It is technically an answer to the question.  (It's even a technically correct answer.)  It's not a *useful* answer, but it is an answer.  This is a good example of why you shouldn't use upvotes to indicate correct/incorrect, but rather useful/not useful.

Comment: @Daedalus Besides being an answer, that's a frickin' good pun joke though!

Comment: @Daedalus So tell me why there are currently 0 downvotes on that not useful answer?  You could have downvoted it.  And of course the meta effect will produce all sorts of weird voting patterns.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Because I didn't think my single down-vote would have any effect on an answer with that many up-votes.  I thought the flag was the way to go.   Guess I was wrong.  But eh; just down-voted it.

Comment: @TinyGiant, wonderful edit over there!

Comment: One one hand, [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/), but on the other we [parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1043380).

Comment: What's all the fuzz about this answer? Compared to the other answers, it seems to be simply the best.

Comment: Just in case anyone missed it, the answer and question were posted *three years ago*.

Comment: @TinyGiant I didn't miss that, though my reasonings would have been applied at that time the same as for the currently active policies.

Comment: Posting non-obvious answers to homework questions is the spice of SO life.  But we are not allowed to have fun and the grinch will show up sooner or later so it must go.

Comment: This might be the epitome of this persistent literalistic NAA asininity. If that post is an answer, then _anything_ is an answer. "Pretend your array is a ham sandwich and peel back layers one at a time until you get to the mustard." is an answer. This post is absolute gibberish as a _code_ answer to a _coding_ question. Saying that this "attempts to answer" the problem is a mockery of the idea of SO.

Comment: Dead wrong.  That this discussion exists is proof that SO is not somewhere I wish to participate further.

Comment: @DavidBullock Then please expand and explain.

Comment: In fairness, I'm less likely to flag something as NAA when it's a joke if it's particularly amusing. As much as I believe SO should limit itself strictly to real, quality answers, I also don't think there's *zero* room for hilarity. The problem is I think a lot of stuff is hilarious that most people think is stupid :/

Comment: Just based on the picture, I'm still missing to see how this actually an answer, let alone a correct one. I am surprised there are people in favor of it. I can't tell if people are just being sarcastic on meta or not.

Comment: @McAdam331 The question asks how to get the fifth element. The code in the answer returns [_The Fifth Element_](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119116/). So, it _does_ get _The Fifth Element_, even if it's obviously not what was being asked for.

Comment: Oh that's just hilarious. +1 if it wasn't deleted

Comment: @reirab so if someone pretends to be an idiot for a minute, they can pretend it's an answer. Then when they return to their senses and stop pretending, they can flag it NAA because it's more than clear that it makes no attempt to address the *actual* question.

Comment: It would be cool, albeit somewhat pointless, if there was a programming language where the above was actually valid code. I believe there is at least one programming language which allows embedded images - HolyC (by Terry Davis of TempleOS fame)

Comment: If it's obviously not what's being asked for, then it's obviously not an answer. I get the sarcasm, and would have no problem with it on Meta, but that shouldn't belong on the main site. I'm appalled enough people were okay with it.

Comment: @TinyGiant I realize this is late, but I've been a bit busy; I don't see how that answer can be an answer to the question.  Yes, the question lacks research, as others have noted, but I really do not see how it can even qualify as an attempt to answer the question.  Can you please expand upon your initial comment?

Comment: It could have been construed as *an* attempt to answer *a* question. NaA flags should be used for posts that could not possibly be seen by anyone as *an* attempt to answer *a* question. If you have a specific reason why you think it should be deleted which does not match the flag reasons available (in your case "it's a joke"), then you *can* use a custom moderator flag. Whether the mod will agree that it should be deleted or not I cannot say. The best thing to do in this case would have just been to downvote it if you think it isn't useful IMO.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I don't think there exists any utterance that can't be construed as *an* attempt to answer *a* question. For utterance X, that question might for example be "what do you get if you add a curly-brace to the end of X, and then remove it again?". Personally I don't feel that's a useful interpretation of NAA, since I think some pseudo-answers should be removed due to not being answers *to the question actually asked*. The issue here, I feel, is not about the definition of NAA (which IMO this clearly falls foul of), it's whether the rules should be ignored in favour of permitting jokes.

Comment: With that said, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag contains a list of reasons to use NAA, and if that list is taken to be exhaustive then this case is not "not an answer". That's not to say it's an answer, just that it isn't covered by anything listed there except perhaps "communicate with another user", which strictly (but uselessly) interpreted could cover any post, including actual answers :-) If none of the questions that it could be an answer to, are valid questions on SO, then I think it fails.

Comment: NaA should be used for things like questions in answers and such that actually cannot be an answer, because they are something else that is mutually exclusive of being an answer. If an answer does not answer the question, then it requires more investigation than is done to validate an NaA flag. When reviewing NaA flag, moderators are not shown the question, they are only shown the answer. So a mod reviewing the flag could think "Well, that could be an answer to a question." which would invalidate the flag...

Comment: Anything other than a clear-cut case of the answer existing in a state that could not possibly be construed as an attempt to answer a question should use a custom flag (excluding content that matches the criteria of another standard flag). That flag may or may not be declined on the grounds that the situation can be handled by the community and does not require intervention by a moderator. We are given downvotes and delete votes for a reason. @SteveJessop

Comment: @TinyGiant: so based on the examples given by an actual moderator in a relevant meta question linked in Josh's answer, if a moderator sees "thanks, I like turtles" flagged NAA, how under your stated rules is that flag evaluated? There do exist questions to which that could be a sincere answer: for example "what's your preferred way of expressing gratitude to someone for introducing you to the programming language Logo?". So should the examples be fixed? Under your rules is NAA basically useless, since there does not exist any pseudo-answer to which it can rightly be applied?

Comment: Within the confines of a question that could conceivably be asked on the site. Should have said that sorry :) Anyways, the standard flags are for blatant cases. Anything else should use a custom flag so you can voice your complaint using your own words. If you're not going to put any effort into describing why you think a highly upvoted post should be deleted, why should the mod put any exceptional effort into investigating your flag? Could it be an answer to a question conceivably asked on the site? Yes. Is it a joke and should probably be deleted? I think so. @SteveJessop

Comment: @TinyGiant: hmm. So it's conceivably the answer to a question in that it contains a code block, and conceivably there might exist a programming language that uses images and in which that's a valid program that does what some hypothetical questioner wants? But if something was flagrant spam contained in a code block, I don't think we'd be splitting these hairs. Jokes seem privileged over spam, which IMO isn't unreasonable it's just not what the SO rules say about jokes.

Comment: Could be, who knows from looking at the answer alone with no other context whatsoever? How is anyone to know that it can't possibly be an answer to a question conceivably asked on the site with just that? @SteveJessop

Comment: @TinyGiant: yeah, so we're back where I started. By this interpretation any utterance X is a potential answer and nothing is NAA, because I could invent a programming language in which X is a valid program and then phrase a question so that X is the answer. If that's really how mods evaluate the NAA flag then I vote to remove it :-) To kick that off, I'm going to design a joke programming language in which the program `Excellent question! Thanks for asking it, I have this problem too` does something worthwhile but *just* obscure enough that someone might need to ask how to do it.

Comment: Again, if the post is asking a question, it could not conceivably be an answer. If the post is just a link, it could not be an answer. Along with many other things that occur a lot on the site (even if you don't see all of them, other users do). It just does not happen to apply in all cases of a post being conceivably not an answer to the question asked. Again. if the flag is going to require any more investigation than being a blatant case of not possibly being an answer to a question conceivably asked on the site, then you should use a custom flag to describe exactly why it should be deleted

Comment: @TinyGiant: OK, if you don't accept my example as a valid NAA, then whatever you *do* think is a NAA, substitute that for `Excellent question! Thanks for asking it, I have this problem too`. So, joke language in which `Your question is very unclear, could you add some code?` is a meaningful program. So that can't be flagged NAA any more, because despite ending in a question mark and also being English, it's a possible answer to a hypothetical question. Surely something can't be NAA just because the answerer might have forgotten to apply the `code sample` formatting, can it? So it's not NAA.

Comment: I'm prepared to believe that custom flags are sufficient, but if so then I think the canned flags should be removed, since they do lead to this uncertainty and disagreement over what they actually mean. Perhaps there could be just one non-custom flag, "it's obvious why this should be deleted", for use when you don't think the mod needs telling.

Comment: Well... I couldn't say. I guess that would depend on a number of variables that I have yet to observe. However, I think if you did make a programming language like that... I would say that there is a high probability that you could be one of those people that [just wants to watch the world burn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efHCdKb5UWc).

Comment: @TinyGiant: if I can make SO burn just by doing that, then SO is insufficiently fire-retardant and needs fixing ;-)

Comment: I do think that the documentation around the flags is severely lacking, however the flags themselves are not the problem. The problem *is* the lacking documentation for the flags. @SteveJessop

Comment: @TinyGiant: well, there's the flag description and the FAQ question and the moderators comments, but *still* we don't agree on  the meaning. I'm not sure this can be solved by documentation, in part because these are inherently "you'll know it when you see it" things that are extremely difficult to fully define.

Comment: Oh there are many ways to better document the use cases for the flags, using examples and such. The fact is that there is a hell of a lot more documentation surrounding the flags scattered around meta than there is useful information presented to flaggers. @SteveJessop

Comment: "Anything other than a clear-cut case of the answer existing in a state that could not possibly be construed as an attempt to answer a question" How much more clear-cut can you get than _an inline image_ as the return value of a block of code, @TinyGiant?

Comment: The fact that the answer got to +43/-2 should be all the proof anyone needs of why flags are necessary and content rating cannot be relied upon unilaterally.

Comment: I stumbled on this question by chance today, and I have edited an [old question I made on the Meta.SE site to include a link to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308374). If baffles me every time, apparently we are so deep into nonsensical technicalities that people argue that these "answers" are made answers by the fact to be posted as answers. This idiocy has been used to post whatever you want wherever you want. I had people hijacking my question with an answer starting with "I know this does not solve op problem but..."

Answer (score 207, accepted):

While I don't know what the reviewers were thinking, the response here on Meta might be the epitome of the persistently literalistic asininity that we see around the concept of NAA. If that post is an answer, then anything is an answer. "Pretend your array is a ham sandwich and peel back layers one at a time until you get to the mustard" is an answer.

Saying that this "attempts to answer" the problem is a mockery of the idea of Stack Overflow. This joke response is exactly the kind of time-wasting non-solution horse manure that I'm supposed to be *avoiding* when I come looking for answers on the premier programming Q&A site in the world.

```
return ;
```

is absolute gibberish as a *code* answer to a *coding* question, and that fact is something that **any** user of this site should be able to discern. [George Stocker's NAA bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268378/603977):

> It should be *immediately obvious* to someone with no experience in the tag that the post does not attempt to address the question.

has clearly been passed with this post. It also falls into bin 5 of [Robert Harvey's itemized list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/603977):

> What mods are looking for when they see a "Not an Answer" flag:
>   [...]
>   5."Thanks," "I like turtles", and similar noise.

and is even compliant with his "Pro Tip: Mods *do not look at the question when moderating "Not an Answer" flags.*" because *there's no need to look at the question to know* that "return inline HTML image of Milla Jovovich;" is a joke.

[animuson also has strongly expressed the idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309300/in-what-sense-was-this-april-fools-post-off-topic-i-dont-think-we-should-be#comment265810_309300) that obviously-joking answers have no place on Stack Overflow:

> If anyone seriously wants this question unlocked, you'd also be asking for us to delete almost all of the total crap answers that are clearly April Fools' jokes because they definitely do not belong here.

If this same content had been posted as a comment, no one would bat an eyelash at deleting it. Its meaning and usefulness aren't changed by its having been dumped in the answer space instead -- although the importance of getting it out of the way certainly has increased.

You were absolutely right to flag this as Not An Answer, and the disputers of your flag were wrong.

Comment: '"Pretend your array is a ham sandwich and peel back layers one at a time until you get to the mustard" is an answer.' - well, technically, it i... dammit.

Comment: Can we lock the answer for historical significance?

Comment: Nvm. The answer^K question is already gone. Deleted after four years of existence. I can't say I disagree with the deletion, at all.

Comment: It's an answer in that it's been filled out in the answer box... and has code... but that's seems to be the only justification.

Comment: +1 for the colorful and hilarious retelling of Meta's tortured relationship with NAA

Comment: Why would it have been deleted without batting an eyelash if it were a comment? Are joke-comments verboten?

Comment: They're not, @KyleStrand, but they're also not considered valuable enough to fret about if they're, for example, in the way of other more substantive comments. I meant that had an equivalent comment been flagged, no one would be defending it as "an answer to the question".

Comment: While (imho) it is indeed not an answer (either to the question or at all) the questionner was shown in a humerous manner that his question lacks substance this way. plus, Milla Jovovich... I would've voted to close the question for not being a question first. Don't knock the importance of fun!

Comment: Now, THAT's a great answer (and THIS is probably a totally superfluous comment :-)

Answer (score 45):

The question may be garbage; it may be downvoted; this answer might be upvoted, but that does not change a bit about the fact that it's not an answer, nor an attempt at one.

In the interest of maintaining SO's professionality and quality I would like to see this Answer removed as "Not An Answer".

Answer (score 44):

> it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they *need* that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content...

([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Answer (score 42):

I agree with your original assessment, and the majority of the answers here: There is no technical value gleaned from the answer you flagged, and that much is obvious whether or not you have knowledge of either the movie or the problem at hand. I agree with the flag, and would have done the same. (The question is also of dubious value, so I'm glad that's gone too.)

I especially appreciate the careful wording of *your* question ("Using NAA on jokes *that make no attempt to answer the question*"), because it allows for the notion that *there are ways to provide a useful, on-topic answer while also maintaining a sense of humor*. Compare:

> If you can't keep a pointer to each list node, keep track of the five most-recently-seen elements, and return the oldest value kept when you reach the end of the list. Pseudocode:
>
> ```
> function GetFifthElement(LinkedList<T> list) {
>   buffer = T[5]  # 5 element array
>   index = 0
>   for (element in list) {
>     buffer[index] = element
>     index = (index + 1) mod 5
>   }
>   return buffer[index]
> }
>
> list = LinkedList("Leeloo", "Dallas", "Cornelius", "Ruby", "Zorg")
> GetFifthElement(list)  # returns "Leeloo"
> ```

*If you don't know the reference, or don't care, you still get a good answer.* If you do, then you get a good answer and a bonus.

StackOverflow is such a valuable resource today because, by and large, the top answers are the ones most likely to teach you something useful or to help you solve your problem. If you can think of a way to preserve that while having a little fun, all the better.