# I can't imagine why this NAA flag was declined

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

Here is the entire answer:

> Very safe: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Granted, this was accepted years ago and it has 91 up votes.

But why is such an obvious link-only answer flagged as NAA declined? Without the link the answer is simply:

> Very safe:

How is that an answer? Why not convert the answer to a comment instead of declining the NAA flag? Was this a mistake or am I missing something?

Here's the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1155027/1226963)

Comment: The question is _How safe is it?_. _Very safe_ is a _poor_ **answer**. The link enhances it a bit.

Comment: Hmm. I guess I didn't consider that. But the question does ask more than just "is it safe". There are several follow on questions at the end of the question.

Comment: Technically, without the link, the answer is actually more like "Very safe: wikipedia Random UUID probability of duplicates". The link text still counts as text; it's only the metadata of the URL, and far more importantly the **contents** of that URL, that you throw away.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Good point. I always think of deleting the URL but I guess the issue is simply with dead links. The Wikipedia link, even if dead, might provide enough keywords to find an updated link. Is that the idea?

Comment: @rmaddy: Yeah, or (in better cases than this) even the keywords there might partially answer the question. For example, if a particular method should be used as the backbone of an answer, and the link text contains that method name, that's of some value as a starting point.

Comment: @rmaddy: In this case, though, about all you can get is that people have in fact considered this problem in some depth before. That's not particularly awesome.

Comment: In my experience these get rejected because technically, in the most literal terms, it is an answer. It's a really bad answer and probably qualifies now more for a 'very low quality' flag then the 'not an answer' flag.

Comment: Both VLQ flags and NAA flags go to [the same place](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/), @j08691. But you're right about the ["technically, in the most literal terms" part](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question/308459#308459).

Comment: @JoshCaswell - If a moderator handles it then it's likely to be rejected it if it was flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: @j08691 There is no option to flag the answer as VLQ, just NAA. How do you flag an answer as VLQ? There are 4 options - Spam, Rude, NAA, Needs Mod Attn.

Comment: The post must have a negative score for the VLQ option to be available.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes because it was upvoted, in which case that flag is removed. You'd have had to flag it for moderator attention if that flag isn't available. But in general, link only answers tend to be rejected by mods if flagged as "not an answer". I'm speaking from my own experience.

Comment: So no one wants to do the very least that could be done to improve the answer? OK, neither do I. Bystander effect FTW!

Comment: @BoltClock Improve it? How about delete it and make it a comment?

Comment: @rmaddy: Why a comment?

Comment: @BoltClock Because it's just a link.

Comment: @rmaddy - then fix the answer, like I just did. Answers like these are tricky because a) it's the accepted answer, so OP found it useful. b) it's highly upvoted so a bunch of people also found it useful. c) wikipedia is unlikely to go away any time soon. So yes, technically it's a link only answer, but there sometimes special cases, especially with older answers such as this one created around the time when the policy on link only answers hadn't been properly set in stone.

Comment: @Kev post that as an answer, please. Rules are there to be applied when they make sense, not to be used so you can nuke what you personally don't like.

Comment: @Gimby -- done.

Comment: IMO, the problem isn't the answer, but the question, seeing as it can be resolved with a quick Google.

Comment: @daiscog that may be true today, but was that true in 2009? probably, *but we can't prove that.* so... not important.

Comment: @BoltClock: That's not necessarily the bystander effect; speaking for myself, I don't think it's _worth_ improving the answer, since there's [another answer posted a minute later](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1155035/603977) linking to the same article, that actually bothered to include some text from the beginning, and a [third answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6963990/603977) that explains the whole thing rather well indeed, while linking to the same section of the same article _as further reading_. I'm not expecting someone else to improve the answer; I'm wondering why they would bother.

Comment: I can't imagine why flagging, deleting, or converting to a comment a years-old accepted answer with 90+ upvotes would ever be construed as a constructive, "helpful", or appropriate course of action.  Editing/improving the answer would be a more rational response than advocating the removal of established, helpful content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Referring to the canonical [*Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), it's an answer. It's not a **good** answer, but it's an answer.

Here's one example from the above that makes me say that:

[image]

Shog9's test is basically: Strip the markup, and if what remains is an *attempt* to answer the question, even if badly, then it's an answer. So stripping the markup from the answer you flagged:

> Very safe: (link to article about) Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

The first two words are an answer. They're not a *good* answer, but NAA isn't about good or bad or complete or incomplete.

Now, if it were:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

**That** would be NAA (*and* a bad answer). Strip the markup and you're left with:

> (link to article about) Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates

Tells you nothing. Does the article say it's safe? Not safe? We don't know.

It's a bad answer that should be fixed (I think it has been now), but it's an answer.

Answer (score 13):

Answers like these are tricky because:

- it's the accepted answer, so OP found it useful.
- it's highly upvoted so a bunch of other people also found it useful.
- Wikipedia is unlikely to go away any time soon.

So yes, technically it's a link only answer but there's sometimes special cases, especially with older answers such as this one created around the time when the policy on link only answers hadn't been properly set in stone.

Alternatively improve the answer, like I just did.

Comment: "Wikipedia is unlikely to go away any time soon" - unless someone sues them for something and they run out of money...

Comment: @daiscog They're [too big to fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_big_to_fail).  In the not too unlikely scenario that the United States becomes a problem, the Internet will treat the United States as damage, and route around them.

Comment: Just because the OP found it useful and accepted an answer is in no way any indication on whether the answer is actually a good SO answer. I've seen many terrible answers accepted by people who didn't know any better. Again, bad, link only answers can be found useful by lots of people. Doesn't mean the answer should be kept. If anything, some of the highly upvoted link-only answers should be made into comments.

Comment: @rmaddy - I'm not going to get into an extended discussion explaining the concept of "nuance". Had I still had my mod diamond, I'd probably have marked your flag as "helpful" because it would have prompted me to improve the question. Anyway I fixed the answer (which you could have done) so it's not a problem now, I'm not going to waste my afternoon arguing the toss about it, and neither should you.

Comment: @daiscog don't believe tales, the Wikimedia Foundation has plenty of money and keeping the lights on would need perhaps 5 % of what it spends. https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia_Foundation_Annual_Plan/2015-16#Appendix_A_-_Budget_Detail

Comment: @rmaddy - You mean the OP and some 90 other members of the community found it useful.  Not quite the same thing as an ill-informed OP accepting a bad answer.  In that case, the 90 other community members would tend to point out that the answer was bad instead of voting it up.  Doesn't necessarily mean that the answer should be kept, but it does tend to imply that the answer shouldn't be removed at the personal whim of one community member and one mod, and should be improved instead.  Which you could have done using a fraction of the effort you've put into arguing for removing the answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a link-only answer.

> Without the link the answer is simply:
>
> > Very safe:

Mostly correct. A slightly more accurate representation would be

> Very safe: look up "Random UUID probability of duplicates" for more details.

since you have to take into account the content that's part of the URL itself as well, though it doesn't add much here.

Either way, even with just "Very safe:", it's already an answer to the question. Without the link, it's a very low quality answer, but very low quality answers still don't qualify for NAA flags. With the link, it's not even a very low quality answer.

Comment: @pnuts Having posted one answer about one particular NAA flag doesn't make me the go-to person for your qualms about the handling of other flags.

Comment: @pnuts In other words, you're trying to raise a possible issue I haven't addressed and don't want to address, and you're doing so in a comment on my answer. That's the wrong place for it.

Comment: @pnuts I have no interest whatsoever in continuing this discussion. If you want to continue it with someone else, I recommend you do so elsewhere. This will be my last comment here.