# I am skeptical about the reason for deleting Jon Skeet's answer on shortest "Hello word"

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, historical-lock

To a question [“Hello World” in less than 20 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes) Jon Skeet has posted an answer:

[image: image description]

This might not seem that funny, but note that this was in 2008. This answer was deleted three years later:

[image: image description]

It was deleted with [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284797/hello-world-in-less-than-20-bytes?page=2&tab=votes#comment8733867_284898):

> Sorry, Jon, but this is getting too many mod flags now. I guess we are serious now. [roflcat.com/images/cats/270911970_db35fdd4ca.jpg](http://roflcat.com/images/cats/270911970_db35fdd4ca.jpg) – [Robert Harvey ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey) `Aug 31 '11 at 14:48`

The problems I see with this now are:

- This answer is historically significant and is referrenced all around Meta sites of StackExchange
- The delete reason makes no sense. There is no mod flag UI for any of the answers on that question.

Maybe it could be undeleted again so that users below 10k rep can also have fun? By fun, I mean being able to make sense of [this post for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9152/209994).

[image: image description]

Comment: Fun? *Fun??* ***FUN?????***

Comment: @Will for user's bellow 10k rep, several meta.SE posts will make no sense, because they link to this answer.

Comment: We, the superior 10k+ userbase, should not concern ourselves with those of lesser pointage.

Comment: @TomášZato What's one of the Meta posts that links to this? It's really easy to update links in posts, I honestly don't see any reason to undelete this.

Comment: @bluefeet I am asking for a reason it's deleted, if the rest of the answers isn't. You know, presumption of innocence stuff. Regarding the link, one that definitely confused me was in this thread, repetitively: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/209994 Just search the word bytes over the thread.

Comment: @TomášZato Sure seems like his answer was a joke in comparison to many of the other answers.  As far as the MSE post, you can easily edit out the link to that answer. Problem solved. Again, I see no reason to undelete an answer that's been deleted 5+ years.

Comment: @bluefeet Argumenting to not change something because it has been that way over a period time is really awkward. [Some call it a fallacy even.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeal_to_tradition) Editing the links out of the comments ruins the jokes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9152/209994 And no, I cannot easily edit locked MSE post. If I could, I'd probably add the image I created there.

Comment: @TomášZato _sigh_ Well you could flag the answer on MSE asking for an edit to the answer but undeleting that joke answer makes little sense.

Comment: @bluefeet You do not really enjoy answering the "*Why?*" kind of questions, do you?

Comment: @TomášZato Why was it deleted? As I said, it was an obvious joke answer. Even several comments by Jon reference he's surprised people upvoted it.   I've added a screenshot to the MSE post, problem solved.

Comment: @bluefeet Obvious joke answer on obvious off-topic question. There are [other joke answers too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/381465/607407). Of course, by deleting them too you could make SO even less fun place - and I'm aware some would like that.

Comment: I support it being deleted. I would also have deleted it.

Comment: In that case we clearly need fun.SE out of your reach.

Comment: @TomášZato Yup which is why there is a historical lock on the post, it's off-topic but many of those actually answer the question. That one doesn't and it was deleted prior to the lock due to quite a few mod flags on it.  Considering it was deleted 5+ years ago, and the MSE post now has a screenshot, there really isn't anything left to discuss IMO.

Comment: @bluefeet, wait, are you saying that you judge post by amount of flags and not its content?

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov the content is delete worthy.  [Using NAA on jokes that make no attempt to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question)

Comment: @ryanyuyu, as I've already mentioned in asnwer, this is pretty valid golfing answer.

Comment: Fairly sure that not even golfers think that this is a valid golf answer, given that it can be the answer to any golf question.  If this is such a big problem that it breaks the Internet (??) then just edit the link to point to archive.org.  And what happened in 2008 really, *really* needs to stay in 2008.  The first year of SO has a lot of broken windows, the site was awash in giggle posts with no practical value.  Most of it is gone.

Comment: @HansPassant As long as there's an interpreter that runs it, [it's fair game](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/31388).

Comment: If anyone is interested, I really don't mind it staying deleted. I suspect it might be better for the whole question to be deleted, but I'm really not going to get worked up either way.

Comment: From the mods statements I think there should really be a place where irrelevant but somewhat interesting posts are moved. Currently, the decisions between lock/deleted are done at random - some "fun" threads are locked, other are deleted.

Comment: Jon Skeet doesn't need you to blow smoke up his bum. It's a useless post on a useless question. Move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is full of similar answers. Either all of them should be deleted or none of them. I don't see why Skeet's answer is singled out. It is also very practical and well in spirit of code golfing answers - if you go to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com where such Q&A are on topic, you'll see that many people INDEED created their own languages just to golf and they do include operators like those.

Comment: And they also apply a ["no loopholes" clause](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) to combat that.

Comment: @ryanyuyu, see this comment: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default#comment4646_1071 - that's the form I see in practical use.

Comment: "many people INDEED created their own languages just to golf and they do include operators like those" [Hello World in zero bytes](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55425/31388).

Comment: I don't see how Code Golf SE's policies on the matter are relevant to a historical question on Stack Overflow. But since you brought it up, there's a big difference between *actually creating a language* that will do things with 0 or 1 characters, and just saying "this language exists" even though it doesn't actually exist. One can actually be run on a computer, the other can't.

Comment: @animuson, just as I've said, you either judge this entire Q and all answers as CG or you don't and offered reason why it is not "useless" in CG perespective. I'm fine with either. What I don't like is exactly "single answer having special treatrement different from all others".

Comment: Your argument makes no sense. The answers were all judged equally based on what Stack Overflow expects of an answer. Code Golf's rules or policies or whatever are completely irrelevant. This isn't Code Golf SE. Jon's answer did not follow the standards *we* have for answers, the others do. What is confusing about that?

Comment: @animuson, one answer treated by ONE set of rules (i.e. "present rules"), other answers are treated by OTHER set of rules (i.e. golfing, as defined by question). If that's crystal clear for you - then well, I'm not you. Besides according to Robert comment, you're lying anyway and real reason was "oh, we got too tired of flags". Deleting for one reason and then trying to paint it otherwise is pretty confusing too. Not that it happened for first time, but still.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Yes, it was deleted because it kept getting flags. Problem is, the flags were **valid**. They had been ignored previously because the moderators just didn't want to delete it. So it was a decision between "delete this answer based on valid flags" or "keep ignoring the valid flags and let more valid flags keep bothering us in the future." You seem to want to make up your own set of rules here, which is not gonna happen. The question is deleted now, so whatever.

Answer (score 21):

This is not a historically significant post.

It is not inherently of high value, nor particularly notable in the culture of the site.

There is no reason to undelete it.

Answer (score 14):

Since it has the historical lock, we can't really take action on it as a community, but here's what I believe.  The question *overall* should be deleted, since it's not all that valuable (if one wants these sorts of answers, [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) is their port-of-call - specifically for "Hello World", [this question would do](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/55422).)

Comment: I completely agree with this. If Code Golf already has their own question for the same thing, there's absolutely no point in keeping the old one on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And since it's so old, no one would lose rep right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu the question and all the answers are community wiki so I don't think anyone had any rep from it anyway.

Comment: @TZHX:  It wasn't made CW until a year or so later afterwards.

Comment: @ryanyuyu:  I doubt anyone would lose rep from it, since all the scores that count would have been above 3.