# Person wrote something as an answer because they could - is it still an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

Someone has posted something as an answer.

It contains code, which, as a rule of thumb, means they have at least made an effort to answer, and thus it can't be flagged as not an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669748/901641

The only reason I'm bringing it up is I asked them "Why did you write this?". I asked because the code is barely related to the question.

Their response was "Freedom. SO gave me chance to did it."

Uh... what? The sole reason this was posted was because it could be?

If Meta didn't exist, I'd ignore it and move on. Since Meta exists, I figure I'll just double check - this still qualifies as an answer, even though the justification for having written it is dubious, no?

Allow Just Do It to change their vote.

Comment: I thought that was the only thing he said...

Comment: @BoltClock - Apologies for the unclear title. If you think of a better phrasing, please change it.

Comment: No, that's fine. I was just appalled to see that he kept going on and on and on until he answered all your questions. He could easily have collected all of his responses in a single comment like you did with your questions...

Comment: You may take my life... but you will never take... MY ANSWER!

Comment: Seems like he wanted to answer the question and gave you a flippant answer.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A user's motivations behind posting an answer doesn't change anything about the answer itself.

If a user is clearly posting nonsense as an answer just because there is an answer form (which, make no mistake, is something real people do on a regular basis), you'll know this type of post when you see it; flag it as not an answer.

If the answer doesn't qualify for NAA for whatever reason, either downvote it if it's benign (i.e. doesn't otherwise qualify for a "spam" or "rude or abusive" flag or warrant further investigation), or flag it for moderator attention if it is suspicious.

That said, if a user is being obnoxious, flag the post or the comment(s) accordingly and it will be handled as appropriate, independent of the quality of the post.

Comment: Reminds me of when everyone said that a picture of the fifth element "was an answer, just a poor one" it was clearly nonsense, yet everyone defended it as "technically an answer" I will use this answer for future references...

Comment: @JustDoIt you mean [this one](http://www.periodictable.com/Samples/005.2/s13.JPG)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak He's talking about this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question

Comment: @cimmanon thanks! Now that I've seen it, I realize that I've seen it before. I even vaguely remembered Tiny Giant's "We Hate Fun™".

Comment: I'd like to take this opportunity to ask for a moderator stance on what qualifies as NAA.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not even sure if we should flag them at all...

Comment: @Braiam Are you suggesting they're OK to have on the site? Or...

Comment: @TylerH here's the thing: I don't know how to interpret this answer. I know all of the others are wrong, but I can't be sure about this one.

Comment: @TylerH: I can tell you that, as the OP correctly points out, the answer in question does not qualify.

Comment: Quality of content over motivations. +1 [Why did you go to so much trouble? BECAUSE!](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/11/03/guys-who-overdo-it-on-stackoverflow/)

Answer (score 34):

If someone posts a bad answer, or an answer that fails to answer the question, then you downvote it.  That's exactly what downvotes are for.

Comment: Laconic answers are always better,+1.

Answer (score 17):

This principle is called "snippet sharing" (at least in my world) and it isn't really addressed on meta that much.

I see it happen with code around HTTP requests a lot: people ask *"Why doesn't this HttpClient.Post() code work?"*, and someone answers *"Try this code I always use to perform HTTP POSTs"*, inviting more cargo cult to the site.

This happens when people think that dumping their favorite script for doing trivial tasks actually helps the OP or later visitors. It may, or it may not.

Assess the answer as just that: an answer to the question. If it doesn't answer the question, is incorrect or otherwise has problems that you can't fix by editing: downvote it and leave it.