# Award Temporary Badges to users who do a good job

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was thinking that it would be great to be able to give someone badges which express how they did something well. It doesn't have to be permanent, it could just be on for a month. I feel it would give more context to up/down voting. And also you could be awarded for good comments as well.

OK so a little context to why I think this feature would be a good idea. I recently asked a question which was answered very well. But then someone commented on his answer to suggest something different and the guy who answered my question tagged me in a comment to raise my awareness to his comment. Now in my books, this is really going above and beyond and I would like to reward him in some way for being such a great user. But I am not able to because I have already marked it as the answer and upvoted.

A few temporary badges I had in mind are

- Detailed Question
- White Knight/Hero - Answering a question correctly after a lot of other people have tried and failed
- Useful Comment
- Above and Beyond - When a user goes out of their way to help you
- No Detail - for when the user just asks a question with no context
- No Question - for when the question just isn't clear
- Unhelpful comment - for when someone is being a deliberate troll but it isn't worth reporting

I can imagine that some of you won't be able to see the point in this, but another area it might help is with anonymous downvotes who don't have the B**ls to tell the user why they did it or how they could improve.

Comment: Why would you want to reward with a badge a user asking a question with no context, or a question that isn't clear?

Comment: And who exactly decides which comments are "unhelpful comment" or "Useful" for that sake, it can't be the questioner because he/she will just mark any comments not solving their issue as "Unhelpful"

Comment: @Tunaki Its more of a more useful alternative to downvoting. Theres been times when I've been down voted and I wonder if it's because the question is bad or whether its because I have asked a question of unpopular opinion. I don't see whats wrong with helping people understand areas of improvement when people are unwilling to add a comment with their downvote

Comment: @Keithin8a alternative to downvote?! What? No. A bad question needs to be downvoted for the longer health of the site. These badges solve no problem on the site and can create the potential for a lot of issues....

Comment: @Patrice Downvotes are rubbish and unconstructive. Ok what about if the badges are permanent on the question and not on the user at all. There are already a lot of problems, people downvote all the time and don't give even the remotest of reasons why, it creates an almost elitist atmosphere where people who want to learn are terrified of asking a question, that surely goes against the whole point of the site. The fact that its anonymous is flawed.

Comment: @Keithin8a OH, THATS WHAT IT IS. You want mandatory comments on downvotes and tried a different way to suggest it. No. Just no. I suggest you try to post constructive comments,help guide gently new users to writing better content. I wonder how much abuse you'll stand before turning to the widespread mindset this is a bad idea. Not saying SOMETHING can't be done. But that is not the proper thing to do. And btw, too many systems (roomba, q bans/throttling, etc) depend on DVs. Your badges,IF they get implemented,should come with an automatic vote.

Comment: @Patrice Did I say anything about it being mandatory? No I think you will find I didn't. It is just a way of enabling users who want to improve quality of questions but don't have the time to explain what the problem is. No one has to use it, that would be stupid because then why wouldn't you force comments. If you must know, ive asked similar questions before, people have provided USEFUL feedback rather than getting angry using caps lock and I have thought about it and came up with an easier alternative. Sorry for trying to improve the site which most of my friends are too afraid of to use!

Comment: @Keithin8a so, that might just be because you don't see me writing enough, but i use caps a lot,not as a sign of anger at all, but emphasis (i knoes i knoes,it gets confusing). Anyway. I dont really see the benefit of the badge then... If i want to be constructive, wouldnt it be better for me to post a comment then a badge that doesnt really say specifically what is wrong? If im willing to give a badge for a bad question to guide the OP, i would be willing to post a comment,no? Or im missing some key thing of your suggestion

Comment: @Patrice It's perfectly possible it might not work the way I intend to. I am giving anonymous downvoters the benefit of the doubt here that most do want to help but can't spend time explaining to people. But as an example,   you might be in work but flick through a few questions in some downtime. You don't have time to explain and get into a discussion with someone about the problems with their question. So you just downvote and leave. Or maybe there are lots of things wrong with a question and you don't have enough characters in a comment.

Comment: @Keithin8a maybe i'm dense, but your badges already correlate to close reasons no? And you might be interested in a talk about mandatory comments.... I dont have the link now (on my cell),but someone suggested to have downvotes should trigger a popup where the downvoter chooses from a list of comments and then posts anonymously. You might be interested in looking it up.fwiw,i am also of the mindset that something should be done for making stack a bit less rough around the edges... Just cant find a good, scalable solution

Comment: @Keithin8a now that I have access to a PC : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253531/enable-optional-anonymous-reasons-for-downvotes-on-questions is what I meant.

Comment: @Patrice That is actually a really good question. has that actually done anywhere do you know? Its been 2 years since it was posted, does anyone ever actually look at things like this to do anything about them? I mean its got a lot of upvotes, surely that should mean its worth a try. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Keithin8a unfortunately there is not a lot of transparency when it comes to Feature Requests and when they will (IF they will) be implemented :(

Answer (score 16):

> I can imagine that some of you won't be able to see the point in this,

Yes, and I'm first on that list. Every scenario you provide is already handled by the system in some way or another. If you post a "detailed question" you'll benefit from a long-lasting effect: *reputation*. That's much better than some temporary badge, both for the user and for the site.

Your request is moreover impractical. Current badges are awarded automatically by the system. So they are cheap. You don't need to gather a bunch of people to look at posts or actions case by case and award badges. Many of those you propose could not possibly be awarded automatically. For instance:

> Unhelpful comment - for when someone is being a deliberate troll but it isn't worth reporting

What? So the user is not reported for "being a deliberate troll" but somehow something must guess that a badge must be awarded?? People trolling in comments are already handled: we flag their comments as non-constructive, or rude if it raises to that level, and the comments are deleted. For cases where someone is doing this habitually we raise a moderator flag and moderators look into it. (And I'd say if there is nothing worth reporting (which on this site means nothing worth flagging) then you're not in fact dealing with a troll).

---

OP commented:

> It wouldn't be automatic, that's the point.

Ok, I admit on first reading I missed this bit: "I would like to reward him in some way for being such a great user." So you want to be able to decide to award badges to users. Still a no go. As mentioned earlier, there are already ways offered by the system to reward people who helped you. The answer you accepted and you think went above and beyond, for instance, can receive a bounty. That's one of the specific reasons for bounties: "reward an existing answer".

Moreover, some of the badges you propose should really be the result of community consensus and not the decision of a single individual. I don't know why the site should highlight the fact that *you* decided that a question was not clear and thus awarded a "No Question" badge. Maybe it is clear to everyone but you. This, by the way, is one of the reasons the system does not add an automatic comment as soon as someone votes to close a question. (The one exception is duplicates.) If it turns out only one person decided to vote to close the question for being unclear, there's no point in having drama about it in the comments.

Finally, I have to come back to this badge:

> Unhelpful comment - for when someone is being a deliberate troll but it isn't worth reporting

So you want to be able to decide *on your own* that someone is trolling? I can already imagine the storm this would cause in comments once people start getting labeled as trolls.

Comment: It wouldn't be automatic, that's the point. Its an alternative to up/down voting, you would award them a badge which would then form part of your vote. It would encourage people to be constructive with their down votes. It would also allow there to be a distinction between a whether a question has been upvoted because it is a great question that lots of people have wondered. Or whether its just well structured as a question.

Comment: Thanks for your update to the answer. Before you posted that, I did not know you could add a bownty to a question which has already been answered. The name to me suggests that it is a request for an answer to a question you feel hasn't been answered correctly. Perhaps I was thinking too much bounty hunter and less bounty treasure. Perhaps this could be the answer, improve the wording of bounty.

Comment: Admittedly, a lot of the badges I came up with were on the fly as I was writing because I thought, the one badge I had an idea for wasn't very constructive as a question. Its also one of the reasons I tagged it as a discussion. In my question Patrice mentioned there is an idea for quick comments when down or upvoting. I think that idea is the exact aim I was going for but I didn't think about the comments thing.

Answer (score 5):

The motivation of this suggestion is fine (except IMO for the „bad behaviour“ badges, those I just don’t understand).

However, most of the ideas would require a human being judging the behaviour - a machine can’t reliably detect „above and beyond“ behaviour nor whether an answer really, truly helped the OP.

We don’t currently have that. Adding it would require massive changes to the way Stack Overflow works, and  to the way how we grade/judge contributions.

That would be a big change and the payoff would have to be something much more substantial than just a couple of nice badges.

Answer (score -20):

I think it is a good idea.

In some cases, I don't think that they have to be temporary (for example, "white knight").

The main problem with it, that it would mean a structural change in the SE software. It didn't happen since years, even from the minor changes happened only a few. The DocSE was an extension to the software, and not an improvement.

Thus, I can't see a big chance that it would ever happen.

Comment: Do you seriously think publicly labeling people as trolls (the last of the proposed badges) is "a good idea"?

Comment: @Yannis I think it would be funny. Don't worry, it would be only temporal. Well, the troll is a too negative word. Maybe "jerk" would sound better. Or some poetical euphemism, for example, *"elephant in the porcelain shop"*. Sad, that there is no really sense of humor in this site. I wrote a [meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284434/259412) about this phenomenon, I suggest to read it.

Comment: @peterh funny isn't for Stack. And this isn't funny, but public shaming. Seems like any user could award this badge on a whim. How many ACTUALLY helpful comments (by high rep users trying to clarify crap questions) will be marked as unhelpful and then good users will be labeled trolls?

Comment: Nothing funny about public shaming @peterh.

Comment: @Patrice I think it should be able to happen only if there are also other, objectively measurable circumstances (for example, in the case of the comments: this or other comments of the user was flagged recently multiple times). I don't think that a temporary badge would be so terrible, particularly if it isn't really insulting. I suggest also to you to read my [meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284434/259412) about the cause of the lack of humor on the SE.

Comment: @Yannis Read some [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/), and have a nice day! :-)

Comment: @peterh already read it. Doesnt change my stance. And the request here isnt for a peer reviewed system, so your last point doesnt really stand. Even if it was a bigger system, what benefit to the site is public shaming?

Comment: Here's a funny meta on humor on Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308441/using-naa-on-jokes-that-make-no-attempt-to-answer-the-question