# Why were four of my comment flags declined?

Tags: discussion, support, declined-flags, comment-flags

Up to now I have flagged over 10.000 comments and I was proud to have only 8 of them declined. Therefore, I thought that I have a good feeling for "no longer needed" comments. However, today 4 of my comment flags got declined. Don't get me wrong, I don't mind the declined flags by themselves. I'm just wondering, whether I or a moderator had a bad day ;)

---

The [first flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475024/whats-the-difference-between-jquery-js-and-jquery-min-js/3475592#comment9566694_3475592) was on a comment that just highlights a point within a relatively short answer:

> most importantly, the brownie points

IMHO, this comment doesn't add anything to the Q&A and appears to be just an opinion.

---

The [second flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603559/store-a-closure-as-a-variable-in-swift/24604820#comment38156103_24604820) was on a "thank you" comment by the OP on the accepted answer:

> That solves it. I'd upvote your answer, but being a newbie, the best I can do is perhaps name a variable in my source in your honor.

It might be witty, but again I don't see any benefit in this comment for the Q&A. Also, [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/).

---

The [third flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182084/cant-start-hostednetwork/19804912#comment29444341_19804912) was on a comment on a post that used to be a link-only answer:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

However, the answer had been properly revised in 2014, so IMHO the comment is obsolete now.

---

The [fourth flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131958/what-is-the-maximum-characters-for-the-nvarcharmax/11131977#comment54811197_11131977) was again on a kind of "thank you" comment:

> great example! it really was helpful to understand what can i do with 2gb of storage.

The "2gb" part refers to a joke in an answer suggesting to put 166 copies of an entire book into a column. Again, this might be witty, but I don't see any further value in this comment.

---

I love to do things right<sup><sub>TM</sub></sup>. Therefore I'd like to know whether my judgment was wrong (and why - I got all of my flags on similar comments marked as helpful before) or whether a (new?) moderator was a bit trigger-happy on the *decline* button.

Comment: So 70+ users found the comment useful and one did not.  And they have to listen to the one.  Makes sense.  I think we can all do without this kind of race to the bottom.

Comment: Just because you've flagged 10.000 comments, it doesn't mean you cannot be wrong. I mean that respectfully, what you are doing is immensely helpful, but remember, the purpose of flagging isn't about your numbers. With that in mind, I do agree with some of the flags you have done.

Comment: @HansPassant: I got flags on comments with more than 100 "upvotes" marked as helpful before. Jokes often get many "upvotes", however, they can distract from having a straight-to-the-point Q&A.

Comment: @Script47: I tried to convey what you say in my first paragraph. This is why I asked whether and why I'm wrong at the end of my question. Up to now I thought I'm doing fine, but now I would like to know whether this is true or not.

Comment: @honk regarding the link only flag, it seems that the OP has updated the post, no? That could be the reason of your declined flag. However, regarding whether you think you are doing fine or not, I'm sure you can tell from your numbers that you're doing fine. Moderators are not infallible, they slip up too.

Comment: Looks like two of the comments are gone now.

Comment: @Script47: I flagged the comment, which claimed that the answer is a link-only answer. But the answer is no longer a link-only answer (since 3.5 years), so I don't see the need to keep the comment claiming that the answer is just a link-only answer.

Comment: your second flag looks definitely correct - this comment is not just a useless joke, it promotes a harmful idea of giving variables cryptic / insider-joke names which make it so much harder to maintain the code (that said I somehow couldn't force myself to flag it)

Comment: I personally see 3 words in the second comment i think are usefull: _"That solves it."_ This states the answer is not only helpfull but also solved the problem. I have seen answers being accepted because they were "the best" but not actually solved the problem. But these words are indeed being overshadowed by the rest of the comment.

Comment: @AndréKool: Up to now all my flags on _"That solves it."_ comments by the OP on the accepted answer got marked as helpful before. I consider such comments redundant, because if an answer gets accepted but doesn't solve the problem of the OP, then I would expect a comment by the OP like: _"This helped me, but didn't fully solve my problem (because...)."_ But, of course, I might be wrong...

Comment: Some moderators think we take the "we hate fun" thing a little too far. Others agree with you.

Comment: @some with regards to fun answers you may want to give a read to [Using NAA on jokes that make no attempt to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308459/839601)

Comment: @BoltClock: If you could find a consent, that would be great. I think all moderators should act in a similar way. I'm looking forward to your   authoritative answer ;)

Comment: @some: In case I have gone too far, I'm happy to adapt my flagging behavior. I just would like to know which comments are acceptable these days and which may be flagged.

Comment: @honk I am with you on this one. I have flagged comments like that, too, and got the flags approved. It surprises me that yours were declined.

Comment: @some It's painful to read a Q&A and have to sift through "witty" comments (especially a back-and-forth between multiple people), whether working a review queue or looking for an Answer. Comments that are "chit-chat" and fine for the moment have no place at a later point in time - they're just noise.

Comment: @some Except that comments are transient by nature and may be removed at any point because they're not appropriate for permanent content such as questions or answers, and therefore there's no strong argument to keeping them around.

Comment: I'd like to add that the thing referred to as "brownie points" in the first comment isn't a joke. Anyone who's worked with SEO will tell you that getting a boost on Google is serious business. With that said, the comment itself indeed added nothing.

Comment: @Wingblade: Thanks, I didn't know that *blush*. Well, English is not my first language, but apart from that I don't have any further excuse. I just fixed the reasoning.

Comment: Here at StackOverflow, we hate fun.

Comment: Looks like a real moderator handled the issue for you. All four comments appear to be gone (which they should have the first time around already). I guess things always become a bit rough, when new moderators join the team.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, they are gone. Interesting. But anyway, I don't mind a bit of roughness; that's why we have Meta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was the moderator who declined those four comment flags. Thanks for calling me out on these so that I can improve and we can come to a common understanding.

---

Upon reflection, the third and fourth should have been deleted. Thanks for your feedback. I'm **really sorry** for this. It's all on me. Please don't let this discourage you from further helping out on this site!

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

&

> great example! it really was helpful to understand what can i do with 2gb of storage.

---

Regarding these comments, apologies for the possible misjudgement on my part, but do hear me out:

> most importantly, the brownie points

and

> That solves it. I'd upvote your answer, but being a newbie, the best I can do is perhaps name a variable in my source in your honor

Although they were borderline pointless and did not add much to the respective answers, those were just more than a simple "Thanks!". Furthermore they were highly upvoted comments and on very old answers. I hesitated to remove these comments as they have been there for a long time (historical/adds personality to the site), especially so when other comments around them have already been removed by other moderators while itself still stands (as I may be missing the historical context here, so I'd rather be cautious).

With consideration of the above, handling "No longer needed" comment flags is tricky in the sense that it is not as straightforward for these type of comments. Being presented with the delete and dismiss options, moderators have to finely balance when a comment merits *some* value, or marking the flag as helpful (delete). I hope this provides additional insight.

Comment: Moderators can't mark the comment flag as helpful without deleting the comment?

Comment: Thank you, Samuel, I appreciate your answer. And I'm not discouraged at all. I'm enjoying the discussion in the comments on this question. As long as we manage to clarify issues, I'm fine. But, speaking of clarifying, it is still unclear for me, whether I should have flagged the "brownie points" and "honor" comments or not. I hope that you and the other moderators can reach a consensus and provide us some guidance here, because I still consider the comments noise.

Comment: @MSeifert last time I checked it was indeed so, mod marking flag helpful deletes the comment (wonder if there is a workaround of marking helpful and after that undeleting)

Comment: Yes, it's not feasible to mark comment flags as helpful without deleting the comment @MSeifert. It's technically *possible* to delete + undelete, but the tools make that a rather roundabout process (open post, delete comments, reload page, open deleted comments, find comment, undelete). And anyway, a comment flag is either right or it's not. Not worth spending more mod time on it than necessary.

Comment: Hi @honk, for the reasons I have specified above, I will recommend reserving the "No longer needed" comment reason for those that are either clear-cut or recent. This is because it all depends on the context, age, historical and future value, number of useful votes on the comment, etc. With only two options presented to us described above, we have to weigh whether the comment is slightly useful (declined) vs deletion (helpful). If you have additional input for us to consider on why a seemingly good comment should be removed, the "Other" option is available.

Comment: People upvote useless comments all the time. Those comments were so blatantly useless that I'm frankly quite surprised someone would put that much weight into those arguably minor secondary factors that completely disregard the actual content of the comment (which should be the most important part and outweigh any other consideration). If there were an answer saying little more than "I'm having the same problem", would you leave that be under the same circumstances?

Comment: @Dukeling "it's too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff. This is why community moderators have real power; they _need_ that power to intervene, educate, and refocus the community's exuberance on more substantive content..." ([The Trouble With Popularity](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/))

Comment: I personally disagree with the decision to leave out those two comments, for the reasons already stated. But I am curious if there is a precedence to the reason: *historical/adds personality to the site*, or if there has been any relevant meta discussion(s).

Comment: @SamuelLiew: Thank you for your clarifying comment. I still disagree with your reasoning (now also because all 4 comments have been deleted), but I don't have the need for an extended discussion. You provided the guidance I asked for and as long as nobody instructs me otherwise, I will adapt my flagging behavior accordingly. No big deal ;)