# Why was this highly upvoted answer converted to a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-answer

I recently noticed that the top voted answer in [How can I create a copy of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794244/how-can-i-create-a-copy-of-an-object-in-python) was deleted and converted to a comment by a diamond moderator.

The post in question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4794254/4909087) one. For <10k users, here is a screencap:

[image]

The timestamp shows this was done sometime in May. From first glance, the answer does not seem to tick any of the boxes that would usually result in answers being removed (The answer is not NAA, and not link-only as per meta's guidelines).

The only reason I can attribute to this is the terseness of the answer, but I do not think that is a valid reason for deletion. I have seen similar single-sentence answers linking to the documentation that have contested and withstood deletion.

So, what was the problem here?

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't really answer the question, just says try *this link*, read *that link* : [Your answer is in another castle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: @mx0 But it does. It tells the OP which function to use, and even links to relevant documentation.

Comment: search for "deepcopy" at question page shows 16 matches, leading to much more comprehensive and useful answers. So what remains in deleted answer besides it, is just a link to another question. Still, at lower viewed question moderators would maybe let it slip, but at 95K views one can argue that question qualifies for thorough ["Atwood cleanup"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103069/165773) which leaves "answers" like that zero chance

Comment: @gnat I understand where you're coming from, but isn't that what the voting system is for? Given enough time, better answers will receive more upvotes, and so be it. Deletion seems like a knee jerk response, and a poor one at that.

Comment: @coldspeed of course not - or more precisely not in this case. Atwood cleanup applies to extremely popular posts where voting works differently. And here is an exact case that shows where and how it breaks. Of 100 thousands visitors some 100 random passers by decided that they "like" this answer (note "like" - Facebook style, [totally irrelevant to content usefulness](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308459/839601)) so that usual math on downvotes to less useful answers won't work anymore

Comment: On the other hand, I flagged [this high-quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18914143/365102), but "a moderator reviewed my flag and found no evidence to support it". ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: @MateenUlhaq fixed.

Comment: There are people who don't like answers that point to the documentation, and there are people who don't like answers that point you in the right direction rather than taking you by the hand to your destination. There are moderators who don't care whether the answer is helpful to the person posing the question, or to other people with similar questions, they only care about whether it meets site-imposed quality rules.

Comment: @MichaelKay SO's **primary** concern isn't with the person asking the question, it is with the 1000 people who show up in the next 5 years with the same question.  Link-only answers have, historically, decayed to uselessness as the target site changes URL schema or whatever.  So answers **must contain** their core advice, and can only use links to augment themselves.  This *both* serves the original asker *and* the 1000 people showing up later optimally.

Comment: @mx0 At *worst*, it's exactly like the "This is an answer" example.

Comment: @AdamNevraumont That may be SO's primary concern, but it is not mine. Particularly when answering questions about my own product. There may come a time when people are still using my product even though the documentation has ceased to exist, but if that time ever comes, then (a) I don't think the random snippets of historical information on SO are going to help anyone very much, and (b) there must be more effective ways I can protect against that eventuality than duplicating information on SO. In any case, I expect my site to outlive SO.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sorry, this was just a slip-up due to mowing through a large volume of flags this season. It is certainly an answer even though it is short.

Thanks for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! This question wasn't meant to point fingers, just for me to understand the reason for deletion if there was one. No need to apologise, moderators are human too! Thanks again.

Comment: You are too kind. Thanks for the understanding. Have a great weekend!

Comment: It would be nice to get some kind of notification in cases like this. I'm happy to improve an answer if there are issues with it.

Comment: true that poster won't even notice it: all rep gained from a 3-month old deleted answer remains, so you can't even be warned by a sudden rep decrease.