# Flagged a "joke" with a custom flag but it got declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295715/convert-vbscript-to-c-sharp/55903009#55903009) the other day with a custom flag.
The flag said:

> This seems to be some kind of weird joke. It's definitely not an answer to the question

It got declined with the reason

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The answer is some sort of attempt of a prank on a naive user. If you were to follow the instructions you would see notepad starting up and then see typing appear in notepad.

It is definitely not a genuine attempt at answering the question. I don't think answers like that have a place here, but it's not spam, and it looks like an answer, so I used a custom flag to indicate just that.

1. Was I wrong to flag the answer?
2. Should I have used one of the standard flags?
3. If not 1 or 2, should I have used a better description on
   my custom flag?

Comment: First of all, you should have downvoted the answer.

Comment: The outcome of the flag notwithstanding, it's too bad you didn't chose to vote on that answer. Voting on this content is very important, and part of the moderation all of us can do. It also helps with curation, since downvoted posts are easier to delete by regular users without involving a moderator.

Comment: @yivi, thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize downvoting had this effect as well. I  usually only downvote "actual" answers, but I see I should change that and also downvote rubbish.

Comment: possibly related: [Using NAA on jokes that make no attempt to answer the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308459/839601)

Comment: I deleted the post now. Screenshot of the answer -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdPfC.png (I usually avoid deleting a post with an ongoing discussion, but that went from 0 to -7 faster than a Tesla, so I deleted it to put it out of its misery)

Comment: Poor homework question, the accepted answer is code-only, boy what a treasure trove :)

Comment: that;s quite harsh for ppl who work hard for their jokes :)

Comment: @BhargavRao Can you please post a screenshot of the question as well?

Comment: @Gab https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS4Z7.png

Answer (score 42, accepted):

3 *or rather* **downvote/comment** + 3

---

I declined the flag on the answer because I was not sure why it was a "joke answer". It had a clear description stating what to do and had a neat code block with necessary code to supplement the description. In short, it had all the characteristics of a valid answer.

Remember that moderators have no idea about the technical aspects of the answer. The more verbose your flag is, the better it is for us to understand it. We do get a lot of flags on valid attempts at answers as "this is a joke, it doesn't work", or "this is a prank, it is not an answer" by users, and the decline reason I used is the standard decline reason for those type of flags.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, if the flag had pointed out that it's a joke answer, how would you know that's actually the case and it's not the other way around (i.e. good answer with prank flag)? After all, you say *"that moderators have no idea about the technical aspects of the answer"*.

Comment: @JJJ all the more reason to decline the flag. It's clearly the right thing to do in that situation, and almost certainly the right thing to do in OPs situation.

Answer (score 18):

Option 3 would be best here. Don't make the mods read and understand a load of code without a clear indication of why. Ideally, don't make the mods think for themselves much at all. In the same spirit as the UX aphorism that *"the user is drunk"*, it can sometimes be helpful to assume the mods are a bit slow-witted when raising flags, not because they truly are, but because processing lots of flags without necessarily taking time to deeply study each one sometimes produces a similar effect. So tell them what they're seeing and handhold them through understanding what it implies:

> This seems to be some kind of weird joke. The question asks to convert some code from VB Script to C#. This "answer" instead exhibits some VB Script code for opening Notepad, entirely unrelated to the code in the question. It is therefore clearly not a real attempt at answering; I suggest deleting it.

That's still well under the flag description length limit, and would probably have resulted in the post being deleted.

Comment: I just had to upvote this. You had me literally laughing out loud at my screen. A needed laugh after meta dramas. :)
It's true, mods are "special" :D

Comment: Eh, your larger point about *explaining* yourself in a flag message is totally valid, but I have to say from experience, some of your flags have come across as extremely patronizing and demanding. I obviously try not to hold any of this against the flagger and just do what is best for the site, considering language barriers and the difficulty of conveying emotion through a purely textual medium. But because you brought it up and are encouraging others to do the same, I do think this is something you should keep in mind.

Comment: I don’t particularly appreciate being treated as a child or if I’m drunk unless I actually am. Focus on explaining the technical stuff that may not be obvious even to the smartest, soberest mods who simply don’t know that language/technology. That’s a more accurate mental model of what’s actually happening behind the scenes anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray Huh. That's some interesting and wholly unexpected feedback. Feel free to indicate (perhaps via chat or a mod message? Not sure what means you have) when you next come across a flag message of mine that you find objectionable; I'd find it interesting.

Comment: @CodyGray As to the point about lack of familiarity with the technology, my impression has always been that that's only one factor at play and probably not the most important one. Even for someone who knows a technology well, it takes time  to properly process what a post or comment says, how it relates to the context in which it's posted, and what actions are therefore appropriate. I don't expect someone churning through a queue to always parse that stuff correctly - I personally can't handle more than a few items in the Close Votes queue before zoning out - and so I try to serve up ... [1/2]

Comment: @CodyGray ... [2/2] that context pre-assembled and nicely packaged for the mods when flagging. In my mind, doing that is *not* about a difference in technical knowledge; it's about the difference in comprehension that comes from me having had minutes to ponder a question (that was probably mildly interesting to me for me to have been viewing it in the first place) before flagging, versus the mods getting hit with my flag without having first taken in the context. Maybe that's actually not as significant an effect as I assume, but in my head that's the main reason to spell things out in detail.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone but myself on that. Maybe other moderators don't take time to "properly process what a post or comment says, how it relates to the context in which it's posted, and what actions are therefore appropriate." I do. If I don't have time to do so, I don't handle the flag. I leave it for someone else who does have time. The only case where I am truly unable to do so is when I simply don't have the relevant context because I don't know the tech. That said, I do appreciate flaggers telling me what they're thinking. It is never advisable to make moderators guess.

Comment: @CodyGray On the tone point, for whatever it's worth - I've just reviewed a few pages of my flags and while I guess can easily see a perspective from which they're "demanding" (since I almost always specify precisely what action I want the mods to take in my flags... although I would think my flags would be less useful if I didn't do this, and don't *think* this is something you take issue with), I can't find any instance of a flag comment I can imagine being read as "patronizing". So an example would definitely interest me.