# What was the reason to decline the NAA flag?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, declined-flags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33260302/4593390) answer is too short to be an answer and useless because it doesn't describe what is a `hash_fun` and how to evaluate strings using it.

Why my flag was declined if the answer is just a comment?

Comment: Because it's not "just a comment". You don't get to say if an answer is objectively useless just because it doesn't describe what a certain function does.

Comment: It does attempt to answer the question. It's of low quality and worth a downvote and if you care enough telling the author what he can do to improve he's answer, but it is still an attempt to answer the question. (It could have be a comment, but could become a proper answer too)

Comment: I was thinking that a narrow/tip should be posted as a comment and that the answers containing a block of code only (like Nandu's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33244255/4593390)) or having bad formatting are low quality ones, so I marked it as NAA.

Comment: I assumed that 'Not An Answer' flag means 'Not Enough to be An Answer'.

Comment: Well, that's not what it means. Furthermore the flag dialog has never implied that.

Comment: Yes, but not everyone understands the short description in the same way. Before asking the question, I've read similar topics. Many of them say that a flag was correct. In the others there are links to deleted posts, so I couldn't verify my assumption. And only after that asked community. But it's not a root of the problem. There is no full description of flags in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) which could be easily found and used as a guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood the meaning of a 'Not An Answer' flag and I am not the only one who did that. You can find that in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/4593390) where you can also read useful answers about purposes of a NAA flag and how it's handled. I will quote only the two first answers which helped me.

Robert Harvey's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/4593390):

> What mods are looking for when they see a "Not an Answer" flag:
>
> 1. Attempts to communicate with another user.
> 2. Using the answer space to ask a question.
> 3. The OP posting an answer to clarify their question or add additional detail.
> 4. Attempts to bump the question as in "I'm having the same problem."
> 5. "Thanks," I like turtles, and similar noise.

Will's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268409/4593390):

> Mods are janitors. They are not supposed to judge the technical
>   validity of an answer. They are supposed to clean up the trash and mop
>   the sick off the floors.