# Add "How to flag?" to the Help Center under the Reputation & Moderation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, help-center

I've recently faced a problem of misunderstanding the purpose of of a "Not An Answer" flag and this problem is very frequent among the users. Therefore we have a lot of questions about declined flags and how to use flags.

Some information about flags already exists in the Help Center, but it's in few topics:

1. [Our model: What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)
2. [Reputation & Moderation: Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)
3. [Privilege: Flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

The full flagging guidance lay in the Privileges and not in the Reputation & Moderation, where probably you want to find it. And there are no links between these pages, except one from [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)
 to [Flag posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

So maybe we should make a solid quidance under the Reputation & Moderation or at least link existing pages? Another impovement is adding links into the flags dialog for NAA and VLQ like it does for others.

This should solve the problem with misunderstanding the meaning of NAA and VLQ flags and allow moderators not to waste their time to process wrong flags and to describe on the Meta how to use these flags.

Below I'll post some links which could be used to compose an official guidance for the Help Center on "Not An Answer" and "Very Low Quality" usage and previously proposed improvements.

Related links about purposes of a NAA and VLQ flags:

1. [Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)
2. [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)
3. [Can we have an unambiguous, official ruling on what the "not an answer" flag is for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167624/can-we-have-an-unambiguous-official-ruling-on-what-the-not-an-answer-flag-is)
4. [The limits to a Very Low Quality answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer)
5. [Is the Very Low Quality flag too ambiguous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous)
6. [Is the "very low quality" flag necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104782/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-necessary)

Related links about flagging improvements:

1. [A minor change to the description of the "not an answer" flag: "the question" → "a question"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag)
2. [Proposal for making the meaning of "Not an Answer" flags clearer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224167/proposal-for-making-the-meaning-of-not-an-answer-flags-clearer)
3. [Proposed improvement to flagging, for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110404/proposed-improvement-to-flagging-for-answers)

Comment: Tentative upvote from me, it is good to keep in mind that this is not a new problem; effort has been made to attack the problem at the source, and that is the descriptions of the flags. Whatever it is changed to, some people understand it and other people read something entirely different in it (see the #2 link under flagging improvements). Quite possibly the help page will have the same interpretation issues, and then the problem exists in two places.

Comment: unrelated: out of curiosity,  have you misinterpreted "Not An Answer" as "Not A Correct Answer"?

Comment: +1, also in addition we should really think about introducing a sandbox for beginners to train how basic moderation tasks such as flagging/reviewing works. Most of us do not learn by reading but by actively practicing. This idea has come up in other meta posts as well, but unfortunately it has not gained many supporters. See e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289871/practice-queues-for-review-training

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I have misinterpreted  "Not An Answer" as "Not Enough To be An Answer". See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308572/what-was-the-reason-to-decline-the-naa-flag

Comment: @cel, The sanbox is an overhead at least at this moment because we have no official documentation which can easily be found. While a sandbox requires writing a code, testing and other stuff, the Help Center and descriptions in the flags dialog can be changed just by editing a text.

Comment: @YohDeadfall, it's definitely necessary to have a reference, but IMO this will not improve flagging in general. We have good guidelines on what is off-topic, yet if you do some reviews in triage you will notice that does not mean people are actually reading it. As I said, big +1, but I think more needs to be done to do it properly :)