# Declined flags on removed old VLQ answers

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

I've raised a few custom flags on link only answers from [Customizing the TreeView to allow multi select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459375/4593390). One of them was on the highly upvoted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25302108/4593390). The post was edited by Cody Gray and the flag was declined. It's probably okay.

But why the other flags was declined if the answers were removed? Are they not helpful?

Links:

1. [Answer by Patrick Klug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459375/customizing-the-treeview-to-allow-multi-select/459557#459557)
2. [Answer by filhit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459375/customizing-the-treeview-to-allow-multi-select/38745987#38745987)
3. [Answer by Govert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459375/customizing-the-treeview-to-allow-multi-select/1476066#1476066)

Clarification. I had no way to flag them using the standard VLQ flag because these answers were too old. Only spam, abusive, NAA, and custom flags were available. Previously in such situation flags were marked as helpful.

[image: Available flags]

[image: Reasons]

Comment: I don't see answers by these users, but I do see comments by them. Are these perhaps answers converted to comments?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes, they were converted to comments.  Given that this meta question says that the answers were deleted, and you can't see deleted answers, you obviously wouldn't see those answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I declined your flags. They all said:

> an old VLQ answer

and I couldn't imagine why in the world you would raise a *custom* moderator flag to say something that we have a built-in flag for. (And whaddya know, we have a built-in flag *decline* reason for that.)

What I did not realize is that you were unable to flag answers beyond a certain age as "very low quality". Apparently that change was made [about a year ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326635). Somehow, I've never run into it, either as a user or as a moderator processing flags.

So, in that sense, I declined the flags under false pretenses, because I failed to make the connection between "old" and not being able to flag as "VLQ". That is my bad.

On the other hand, I stand my decline. If the answers were of sufficiently low quality that they needed to be deleted by a moderator, you should have just flagged them as "not an answer". Putting aside plagiarism and other types of fraud, that's really the only reason we're going to step in and delete an answer. (Yes, this means I do not believe there is a functional difference between NAA and VLQ flags. That's a discussion for another time, though.)

As in many cases, I declined the flags (because I felt they were presented in an unhelpful way) but still looked at the answers. It was pretty clear to me that <s>a couple of them</s> they were not answers because they consisted of nothing more than links, *sans* explanation, so I converted them to comments. <s>On the third, there was a link to OneDrive, so I salvaged the answer by inlining that code into it. (An edit that you could have done yourself, by the way.)</s>

This is a well-established reason to flag something as "not an answer" (NAA).

---

**Why are you so strict about declining custom moderator flags?**

For basically the reasons it says in the canned decline reason: using standard flags allows us to better organize and prioritize flags. We can get into the right mindset and process flags much more efficiently. The custom flags are all different and therefore are more difficult to handle. They also tend to require more thought. It's critical that we have them available, and most of the custom flags we get are important, so I'm not trying to discourage their use. I just want to make sure that they are reserved for cases where they are actually necessary. If a standard reason will do, use that one.

Plus, for NAA/VLQ in particular, raising one of these flags will let the community have first crack at handling it, and I'd really rather have that happen anyway. No reason for a moderator to take unilateral action when the community can cast their own votes to delete. This also leads to more involvement of people with domain knowledge, which is way better than a moderator who can only look superficially at the *form* of an answer.

For what it's worth, when I do get involved with NAA/VLQ flags as a moderator, I tend to be pretty lenient in how I resolve them. If I can understand your rationale for raising a flag, I will often mark it as "helpful", even if I ultimately chose not to delete the answer. For example, I kinda agree with Brad Larson about [the pointlessness of deleting old, highly-acclaimed answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332607/why-were-these-two-naa-flags-declined-for-link-only-answers-one-of-these-being/332611#332611) when deletion would make the Internet a worse place by removing useful content. Obviously, if the link has gone dead and the answer has become worthless, I'll delete without batting an eye. Also, if the question has received other, better answers, I'm more willing to pull the trigger. But if that's the only answer to the question, then I generally feel that I'm destroying value by deleting it, so I won't. I'll still mark the flag "helpful", though, because I don't want to send the message that it is inappropriate to flag such answers. In other cases, I'll edit the answer myself to expand it. I'd prefer if the flagger did this themselves, but I'd still rather edit than delete.

**Why aren't moderators more consistent when declining flags?**

Because we are human beings; Stack Exchange hasn't figured out a way to replace us with robots yet. (And once they do, we'll be obsolete, because the posts we were formerly called upon to evaluate and delete can just be blocked from ever being submitted in the first place.)

That being the case, there are places where we disagree with each other, and because different moderators process flags at different times, there's no guarantee that they'll be resolved in exactly the same way every time. I realize that this can be kind of confusing, but you need to look at overall patterns in your flagging history, not isolated incidents. If you are uncertain about why a particular flag was declined, then it's totally fine to ask about it, but resist the temptation to try and make every response into a "rule".

**Specifically, why does [Martijn say that we should raise custom flags for "link-only" answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553), when you seem to be saying that we should just use NAA?**

Well, partially because we disagree about that. A lot of this ultimately goes back to what I think is utter absurdity regarding the interpretation of the "not an answer" flag. In particular, the decision-rule that considers whether the answer is "an attempt to answer". Martijn is saying that, in cases where you want to flag a link-only answer but that answer appears to be an attempt to answer, you'd need to use a custom flag to explain that, because a NAA flag might get declined. I don't apply that "attempt to answer" standard to NAA flags because I think it's rather absurd. All kinds of things can be an "attempt"; we don't judge *attempts* here, we judge *results*.

So, my criteria for NAA flags is quite simple: does this answer need to be deleted? If it's written in a foreign language or it's gibberish, then it needs to be deleted. If it consists of merely a link to an external resource, then it is not, itself, an answer to the question and needs to be deleted. If it asks a new question, or merely adds supplemental information, then it's not an answer and needs to be deleted. If it's not inhabiting the same universe as the question (like, a C++ answer to a Python question), then it's not an answer and needs to be deleted (this doesn't take technical knowledge to judge). The only exception is that we don't judge technical merit or correctness, so *wrong answers* should not be flagged. I will decline NAA flags on those answers, just like everyone else. As such, if I'm going to delete an answer containing a link, it's because the entirety of the answer is buried behind the link—and that means a NAA flag is totally appropriate (and preferable, for the reasons given above).

That said, the larger point of what Martijn is trying to say—if you come across an unusual case that might not be immediately obvious, you should raise a custom flag and explain clearly, rather than trying to pigeonhole it into a standard flag— is something I agree wholeheartedly with. Had your flag contained more information, it would not have been declined. Say, for example:

> This is an old answer that consists of merely a link to an off-site resource, but I can't flag it as VLQ. Please delete it.

Clue me into what you're thinking and *why* you're raising the flag that you are, please. Detail is good. Like Martijn said, don't leave us guessing. I had to do too much guessing here.

Also, I will try and be a bit more judicious when declining "this is a link-only answer" custom flags in the future, given what you guys see as the "official" guidance and the general feelings of other moderators.

**Isn't "very low quality" a really stupid flag?**

Yes, it is. You are totally right about that.

I treat VLQ and NAA identically—both are requests for an answer to be deleted because it is adding no value whatsoever or is actively harmful (but not actual spam or rude/abusive, by our standards for these).

There is no reason to make fine distinctions about which answers should be flagged as VLQ or NAA. If an answer needs to be deleted by a moderator for quality-control reasons, then it doesn't matter which one you pick.

Comment: Two of the answers had a positive score, and so couldn't be flagged as VLQ even if they were recent, as they need to have a negative score to be eligible for VLQ.

Comment: VLQ is such a stupid flag….

Comment: Fortunately there's never any reason to ever use it, as it has 100% overlap with other flag reasons, so all of it's problems don't actually matter.

Comment: Agree, it's a stupid flag. Found an [evidence(4th pic)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) why they should be flagged as NAA.

Comment: At the same time (from [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)): If you do find a link-only answer (especially one with a dead link), it is probably better to use the other flag and explain to the moderators why the post should be deleted. Don't leave the moderators guessing, be explicit rather than use a NAA flag for such posts.

Comment: @YohDeadfall And you didn't do that.  You just said that the post was VLQ, you didn't explain to the moderator why the post should be deleted.

Comment: @Servy Previously such flag with the similar message was accepted, and I thought that the unable VLQ flag feature is well known by mods.

Comment: @YohDeadfall Some mods like to mark invalid flags as helpful because they don't like having to deal with people complaining about their improper flag being declined.  Cody apparently chose not to do that, and correctly indicated that you used the improper flag, as is explained in the decline reason.  The VLQ flag isn't available in lots of situations for very good reason.  If SE wanted people to be able to cast them on any post then those restrictions wouldn't exist in the first place (although, as I said, there's never a reason to use VLQ in the first place, so it's rather moot).

Comment: @Servy I've made some research and found that info about link-only answers on SO Meta was changed yesterday ([before Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/265553/19)). Now it includes that NAA should be used for that kind of answers. So you're right, but we still have confusing descriptions and meta posts, and no direct links to explanations how to flag.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm a little curious about [the one you edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25302108/3). There was no license associated with the code that was posted on a 3rd party site (it was on OneDrive, not a GitHub gist). Doesn't that mean it [shouldn't be copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348698/edits-that-add-ops-code-from-3rd-party-site-where-the-license-is-unavailable#comment470454_348698)?

Comment: @YohDeadfall That post has said for many years that link only answers are (with a described exception) not answers.  It was recently edited to better clarify this, but it has been well established for quite a long time, even in that post.

Comment: @Andrew Umm...I for some reason obviously thought it was a gist and their license is essentially compatible (like PasteBin, which is also cc by-sa). I don't think that applies to OneDrive, so I guess I was just trying too hard to salvage useful content rather than remove it. Sorry about that. I've rolled back and deleted. Since the poster is still an active user, I've asked him to consider relicensing.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that about PasteBin--I had somehow glossed over that part of the question. At risk of driving you insane, do you happen to have a link that says gists are cc by-sa? I don't see anything like that in Github's [terms](https://help.github.com/articles/github-terms-of-service/#5-license-grant-to-other-users). (IANAL, but I _think_ that the definition of "Website" in the terms can be construed to cover gist.github.com, and that site links to the same terms.)

Comment: @CodyGray The VLQ flag isn't available on posts older than 7 days. Meaning you can't flag it as VLQ, and the only remaining option (assuming it is an answer, but i.e. link-only, meaning not NAA) is the custom mod flag. How do you flag in those cases?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use a custom moderator flag to flag non-answers as being not an answer.  You should use the Not An Answer flag to flag non-answers as non-answers.

Moderators will decline custom moderator flags that ought to have been flagged using one of the other flag reasons.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't flagged them as NAA. Since they were answers even link only. I've used a custom flag with the "an old VLQ answer" message. The standard one isn't available on old posts.

Comment: @YohDeadfall I know you didn't flag them as NAA.  That's why your flags were declined.  You flagged answers that aren't answers using a custom mod flag, when you should have used NAA.  That's *what you did wrong*.  When you use the wrong flag reason, your flag is likely to get declined, even if another reason would apply.  The answers were *not* answers, the answers directed to other places that may have been answers.  That's not an answer.

Comment: Nope, [I shouldn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined/268438#268438). If it's an attempt to answer, then it's an answer. I've learned [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308572/what-was-the-reason-to-decline-the-naa-flag/308579#308579).

Comment: @YohDeadfall "link only" answers are valid to be flagged as NAA, but you should think about editing old "link only" answers before flagging. If they can be edited to match site rules, then do that instead. About your case linked in "that": even a custom flag won't cause a mod deletion here, since it "tries" to answer. Downvote is the only thing to do here (next to writing a comment on that post requesting improvement, like you already did).

Comment: @YohDeadfall Posting a link isn't an attempt to answer, it's an attempt to direct the user to an answer that is somewhere else.  Directing the user to an answer that is somewhere else is not posting an answer, as there is no intention of the answer actually answering the question.

Comment: @YohDeadfall hahaha, sorry. You have fallen into the good ol' meta-makes-no-sense-and-isn't-consistent-at-all problem. If you strip markdown and those offer information about the solution to the problem, NAA should be used

Comment: @Servy - re: link only answers as NAA... It depends who you ask. :-/ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332611/3033053

Comment: @silencedmessage Just because you can point to someone who doesn't like the established policy doesn't change the fact that it's the established policy.

Comment: @Servy Just pointing out the inconsistency, not arguing the policy.

Comment: @silencedmessage Brad is saying that he dislikes the policy, and that he choose to intentionally violate the policy in that particular situation, not that the policy is that link only answers are answers.  As you can see, others did not feel that Brad's intentional disregard for the policy was appropriate.