# Declined Flag on Question Where All Answers Are Bad

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914962/is-mule-galaxy-integrated-into-mule-esb

On this question, none of the answers really are suitable for SO. They scream comments. But my flag was declined. Why was it declined for an answer that says "but plugins exists" and doesn't give details?

Comment: what did you flag it as? you also have to have the correct flag reason

Comment: I flagged as not an answer, because I felt it was more of a comment.

Comment: I think the question is the problem there. All of those answers seem to be answering the question that was asked.

Comment: @BilltheLizard bluefeet wouldn't do it but you should totally bounty me 8747 rep so I can delete vote the question :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268369/why-was-this-not-an-answer-flag-declined)

Comment: The question is now closed, but is being held back from automatic deletion by the accepted answer. Some users with delete votes will have to intercede for the question to be deleted.

Answer (score 5):

> Why was it declined for an answer that says "but plugins exists" and doesn't give details?

That's not "Not an Answer", that's just a *bad* answer.  You downvote bad answers, you don't delete them.

Comment: I dunno, if answers are detrimental to a newbie's learning, then I'd argue that they *should* be removed.

Comment: I would consider this to be VLQ.

Comment: I have to disagree, maybe it does answer the question, but it's a comment. It doesn't provide any help beyond "nope it's gone, but stuff exists"

Comment: @ndugger And yet that's contrary to SE's policy.  If you don't like an answer, or even feel that it's harmful, you can indicate that through voting, but answers aren't deleted just because you don't like them.

Comment: Sure, I don't disagree with you, but maybe we should address SE's policy, then? The last thing we need on this site are more, "just use jquery" answers.

Comment: @rlemon 1) he didn't flag it for that reason 2) No, it's not.  It even answers the question.  VLQ is for content that is complete and utter trash, and irredeemably bad.  An answer that is lacking details meets none of those qualifications.  It's low quality, but not VLQ.

Comment: 1) I'm aware, I'm telling you my thoughts on it. 2) I disagree, and I'll repeat. I consider this to be VLQ.

Comment: @SterlingArcher No, it's not a comment, it's an answer.  It's answering the question, it's just doing a bad job of it.  Comments aren't just where you put "bad answers".  It's where you put stuff that isn't even trying to be an answer at all, such as clarifying questions.  If you don't like the answer, downvote it, don't claim that it's a comment when it's not.

Comment: @ndugger Then ask a question where you propose changing the policy, explain exactly what you want to change, and why it will be beneficial to the site.  This question is asking why his flag is declined, and I've explained exactly why his flag was declined.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: @rlemon So you know that it doesn't at all meet the qualifications for what VLQ is defined as, but you just don't care?  The definition of the term here unambiguously doesn't apply here.  As I said to ndugger, if you want to propose a change to the policy, then go ahead, but as it is just saying, "I disagree" without providing *any* supporting statements is pretty meaningless.

Comment: You've read my comments, so you understand **I** consider this a very low quality answer. It is a [meta-tag:discussion] thread and I'm putting in my two cents. you can take it or leave it, my opinion of the content quality is not going to change. Also, what supporting statements do you want? That it is a low quality answer which (imo) does not attempt to give a proper answer to the question. We disagree on this, but that doesn't make it meaningless..

Comment: @rlemon It's not a matter of opinion though.  I can't just say that it's my opinion that the sun exploded yesterday and tell anyone who demonstrates otherwise that it's my opinion and it's not going to change.  Very Low Quality is a defined term, and these answers don't meet that definition.  That's not a matter of opinion.  You can dislike SE's definition of VLQ, and feel that it should be changed; that's something you can have an opinion on.  That doesn't make these posts VLQ though.

Comment: @rlemon I don't disagree at all that it's a low quality answer.  **You downvote answers that you feel are low quality**.  The Very Low Quality flag is another matter entirely; it, unlike votes, has a very strictly defined definition that these posts don't match.

Comment: @ndugger if answers are detrimental to a newbie's learning, then I'd argue that showing them downvoted is better than deletion.  eg: "this is what not to do"

Comment: @BobNocraz On top of that, the whole point here is that these answers are simply lacking in information; people aren't arguing that they're wrong, or promoting an actively harmful solution.

Comment: @rlemon I've seen confusions regarding the VLQ and NAA flags a lot. I think I agree with the bias that 'VLQ reason is reserved for answers like *asdfghjklsdfghjsdfgh*'. → http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93595/is-the-very-low-quality-flag-too-ambiguous

Comment: @Servy okay, and keep remembering I said "**I consider this VLQ**", any conjecture on your end about my considerations is pointless because that is my consideration. On a related but separate topic, SE's definition for VLQ is bad IMO.

Comment: @BobNocraz I suppose there's merit to that as well, yeah.

Comment: @servy Anything that can be flagged NAA can be flagged VLQ.

Comment: @rlemon Then ask a question where you propose changing the policy, explain exactly what you want to change, and why it will be beneficial to the site. This question is asking why his flag is declined, and I've explained exactly why his flag was declined.