# Is an answer that says that there is no answer a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, flags

[Do Ternary and If/Else compile to the same thing, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35189762/do-ternary-and-if-else-compile-to-the-same-thing/35189935#35189935)

The link above points to an answer that says that java is slow, and claims that there is not an answer to my question despite the answer written 6 minutes before. Does this count as an answer? Should I flag it as not an answer?

Answer (score 6):

No, do *not* flag. It is valid as an answer; it's not spam, random gibberish, or irrelevant to the question. See also [Why was this 'not an answer' flag declined?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/2564301) for "Flagging as Not an answer".

The fact that it says "this can't work" is irrelevant, because answers do not need necessary be able to say how something can be done, they should help the OP in answering the question (which sounds like the same thing but actually is not).

The fact that another answer says it *can* be done merely seems to indicate one of the answers is wrong, and should be downvoted.

Which one I'll leave up to field experts - I see a discussion is already initiated.