# Are answers that say that the question is unsolvable not answers?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers, review-audits, review-suspension

I recently reviewed in [late-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) and came across [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/19496835). I did not flag it and thus failed the audit (and got suspended for 2 days). Reason: "Not an answer". I don't see why though. To be fair, the audit answer is kind of poorly worded, but it is, in my opinion, a valid answer.

The audit answer pretty much says that the question is unsolvable with the current version of `flutter_audio`. This should be, according to [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316129/5117236), a valid answer.

Following [the link to the GitHub issue](https://github.com/evrone/flutter_audio/issues/2) he provided, proves, that the problem might really just be a bug.

Also consider: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252170#comment8137_252479

Comment: Those kind of answers are indeed very rarely appreciated.  You failed the audit primarily because you didn't see that post was deleted.  Happened a month ago.  Always important to look when you are going to disagree with a flag from a concerned SO user, very hard to fail an audit that way.  Do focus on all the other audits you got wrong as well to get ahead.

Comment: I wouldnt have flagged it. No is indeed an answer IMO. They _might_ have thought it is link only.

Comment: That answer is essentially a link-only answer. If you remove all the fluff it only says "I opened a ticket (link), look there for more information".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fia2oWoUanA

Comment: IOW the audit system remains broken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should "impossible" questions be handled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333921/how-should-impossible-questions-be-handled)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Insofar as that post is affirmatively saying,

> This is not possible based on the current version of the library. I have filed a bug to have it resolved, but until it is fixed, what you want is not possible.

then it is an answer.

However, the exact language of the answer makes it very difficult to distinguish the above possible intent from the possible non-answer,

> I couldn't figure out how to solve this problem either, so I filed a bug.

Read in this way, this isn't an answer; it's just me-too noise.

Ultimately, I think the post is vague enough that it's not clear whether the poster is saying "This can't be done" versus "I couldn't do this" and that distinction is critically important in assessing whether it is an answer or not. You interpreted it charitably; others did not.

---

I'm not sure how to conclude this meta post. I'd personally say it "unclear if this is an answer" while to you, it *was* clearly interpretable as an answer. I don't think this is a great audit question, since it seems like reading as an answer and reading it as not an answer are both reasonably justifiable.

Comment: Indeed. "This is a confirmed bug/limitation, see GitHub issue #2743" is an adequate answer for this kind of question; however, things become much iffier in the absence of a conclusive diagnostic.

Answer (score 5):

That is a valid answer: the problem cannot be solved is an answer to "how do I solve this problem".

Answers don't need justification to be answers.  They may need justification to be *good* answers, so feel free to downvote a poor answer.

"Not an answer" is about things that are **not an answer**, not "this is a bad answer".  The not an answer flag has been abused here, and your choice was correct.

Comment: I disagree. As @apsillers points out, the answer could be interpreted as acceptably answering the question, or as not answering the question at all. The **not an answer** flag is appropriate here, but so is not flagging. "Your question has no answer" doesn't answer the question (flag), but "I've filed a bug, you'll have to wait for a fix" is a valid solution to the problem (upvote). It's a matter of semantics, and it's subjective. Ultimately it's just a bad audit question.

Comment: @Clonkex Someone says "How can I learn to lift 1 billion tonnes?"  If someone says "You cannot do that", that is **an answer** to the question.  The **point** of not-an-answer is to remove things like comments, comment replies, cats walking on keyboards, links that become completely useless if they go stale, etc.  "This cannot be done" can be 100% perfectly correct answer to a "how" question.  It can be *wrong*, it can be *unsupported*, but that isn't what **not an answer** is about.  Wrong/unsupported means **downvote**.

Comment: That's obvious for such a hard-and-fast example (though still subjective semantics), but much less obvious for the answer in question (no pun intended). The answer says "I encountered this same problem and believe it to be a bug". That's not an answer, that's just a comment. It doesn't help the OP directly and should be flagged. But as I mentioned before, it also _does_ help the OP indirectly, and for that reason it shouldn't be flagged. Finally, it's worth mentioning that answers on SO are expected to directly answer the question, and if they don't, **not an answer** can be appropriate.