# I flagged an answer as "not an answer", but it was declined. Why is this considered an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16140807/selecting-database-within-codeigniter-can-not-select-database-now/41359421#41359421) as "not an answer"; as I think it is much more of an comment than an answer.

Got back "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"

Can anybody explain to me what why it holds up as legit answer?

Comment: Looks like the answer has now been deleted? In any case, I feel like the guidelines regarding the "not an answer" flag are pretty ambiguous, especially since moderators reviewing the flag don't actually get to see the question (which I think is simply bizarre--it seems obviously true to me that some posts constitute an answer to one question but not to another, but apparently it is obviously *false* to the SO team).

Comment: @KyleStrand: The fun part, of course, is that regular users in LQP *do* get to see the question, and not infrequently react in an entirely understandable way when they see a Java answer to a C# question or the like, despite that creating inconsistencies with the more common mod responses.

Comment: Here's a new question about NAA flags and the information shown to mods. As a bonus, the first (and so far only) answer shows a screenshot of what the mod tools look like. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341797/1858225

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It reads as a possible solution to the problem.

Yes, it's short. An answer being long is not a criteria for it being an answer.

Sure, it needs some editing and it's not super informative. But it has a suggestion to try:

> you try update Privileged Users of database in cPanel

If I were researching this and that were the only answer present, I would try what the answer said and see if it helped. (Then edit the answer to improve the grammar, and perhaps comment that the user should consider adding some explanation.)

Looking at the answer in isolation, as mods get it when it's flagged, that is a (rather poor) attempt to answer the question. Keep in mind that comments aren't meant for proposing solutions- Those belong in the *answers.*

If the answer is wrong or bad, it should be downvoted. If you think you can edit it into shape, go for it. But as it stands, that looks like an answer, smells like an answer, and should be in the answer section.

Comment: If you can prove it's a WAG, then sure, provide that proof to the mod with a custom flag. But if you can't prove it's a WAG rather than a poorly worded suggestion, I doubt your flag will get much mileage. @CodyGray

Comment: What you're calling a "suggestion" is indistinguishable from what I'm calling a "WAG". There is no reasoning provided in the answer to suggest that the person has any idea what they're talking about. They're just speculating wildly. If that has any value at all, it is as a comment. I have higher standards for the answer box.

Comment: And you have the rep to both downvote and vote to delete, @CodyGray, but for the rest of us who could only downvote or flag here, it's more likely that our flag is not going to do anything. Again, we don't know if the user knows what they're talking about. It could very well be that they don't know they need to explain their answer better. The answer can always be edited to be improved, or deleted by high rep users if necessary, but the answer reads as an attempt to answer. Attempts to answer, what I've been calling "suggestions" because that is shorter, go in the answers and not the comments.

Comment: WEVER IZ WAG LOL?

Comment: Well, I had defined it in my initial comment, which has now been deleted. Presumably because someone was offended by a three letter word beginning with A. It means "wild-butt guess". @braiam

Comment: @CodyGray the obscenity rules frequently produce such results; include one naughty word, and some censorious dick can freely nuke it from the comment thread with a single flag without any moderator oversight, leaving the entire comment thread an incoherent mess. It would be better if such words were blocked outright, so that we could at least avoid being in danger of a single tosser unilaterally destroying our content, but that's not the way things are. Is this comment, for instance, unilaterally deletable? No way to know but for somebody to try.

Comment: I know, right? I can't believe someone ASSASSinated my comment, @Mark.

Comment: @CodyGray BUT That hurts them children!

Comment: @GhostCat children a'right!

Comment: @CodyGray I agree in principle that bad answers have no business being in answers, and I don't personally object to posting comments that untested, unresearched, or unflushed-out suggestions are better posted as comments to give others a general direction to look in. As far as official policy goes, though, my understanding is that such comments are generally unwelcome and subject to deletion at any time, and answers containing them are certainly not flaggable as "not an answer" under the official policy. So it seems like the official policies nudge you toward putting them in answers.

Comment: And you wonder why the site has quality problems, @jpmc. What good is the Meta site if not to change brain-dead policies? Remember, the site is moderated by the community and all that official policy?

Comment: @CodyGray I didn't say it's a good policy. I only said it's the official policy. Furthermore, it's an official policy that users have been objecting to and arguing vehemently against for literally *years*, and SO hasn't done anything to change this. In the end, it's not my site, and I certainly can't say I've ever successfully run a site like this. Maybe there's something about it I don't really get, or maybe SO just doesn't actually care about quality anymore. Either way, I'm just making a statement about what the current situation is, and attacking me for doing that makes me want to give up.

Comment: @CodyGray Although maybe trying to convince them to be more lax about "suggestion" comments might be something new to try. I don't know if it's ever been brought up/discussed here on Meta.

Answer (score 0):

See [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216712). "Not an answer" is for [I like turtles](https://youtu.be/CMNry4PE93Y) or *purely* link only content. It is *not* for answers that are factually incorrect, are not quite applicable to to the particular question, or answers that need further explanation. Downvoting is the proper reaction to those problems.

Yes, a significant portion of the community believes this is kind of silly. It's the official policy regardless.

Comment: As a side note, I'm amazed a person can acquire 25k reputation without knowing about this. It's been debated to death here on meta.

Comment: The "flag" description explicitly says *This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a* **comment** *, another question, or deleted altogether.* I have seen many flags on such kind of answers that were either deleted by moderators; or turned into comments. And I am only a "more interested" SO user for the last 7, 8 months. During that time, mostly focusing on that rep part.

Comment: @GhostCat As I said, this has been debated *to death* on meta. Go find the relevant threads. Try http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286229/1394393, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268369/1394393, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/216712 for starters. The description is known to be confusing. You won't even get consistent mod behavior because some mods will go the extra mile and look at the question, but they're not required to. (I can't find the post where a mod mentioned that they do  this, but I know it exists.) I don't like it anymore than you do, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @GhostCat Found the post I was thinking of: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318959/1394393.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that downvotes on Meta can just as easily mean "I disagree" as they can "you're wrong". It's very hard to distinguish between an answer that *endorses* the official policy, versus one that simply *summarizes* the (perceived) current/official policy. I realize you are trying to do the latter, but answers like this that become highly upvoted imply community *consensus* for this policy, and that is not something that I want to imply. Such is why I downvoted your answer. Apologies, I didn't mean for it to offend you. It doesn't affect your rep.

Comment: I understand your point. Yes, I'm well aware of the "disagree" usage for downvotes and the fact it doesn't affect my rep. I hadn't considered the implied "community consensus" aspect, though, when the "disagree" usage doesn't seem directly applicable to a statement of well established facts. Thank you for explaining.