# NAA Flag declined for code of a question

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69904097/i-have-a-problem-why-the-time-doesnt-work-in-tempmute-command) put their code as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69904103/15781079). I flagged as NAA but it was declined with this reason:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Was there maybe a lack of context?

Comment: The reviewers can only see the answer, so if it looks like an answer, then you'll get a declined flag.

Comment: "Was there maybe a lack of context?" Yes, that's certainly the problem.

Comment: @Daedalus however they do *not* attempt to answer. It's details for their question

Comment: @MrMythical I saw the answer.  It's a code dump.  It looks like an answer to me, even if it is a bad one.  The duplicate details this.  There is no context that will allow anyone to see this in the review dialog, which is the problem.  This is not to say that I think it is an answer; I believe you, what I'm saying is that it _looks like one_ without any context.

Comment: What should I do now? Ignore it? Flag for moderator attention where I can also describe the context? Something else?

Comment: @MrMythical [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/785241) is perhaps a better duplicate.  But to answer the question you just asked, use a custom mod flag.

Comment: I really don't understand all those claims about context regarding NAA flags... There is a "Question" tab right there in the review. The context is just a click away...

Comment: This seems to be just an honest mod mistake. Ignore it and move on. In future when this happens, use custom mod flag to clearly explain why you think the answer is NAA and should be deleted.

Comment: @Tomerikoo At the time those duplicates were created, we were always told there was no context of the question in the flag review dialog.